# How do I fix broken Git history after migrating from Subversion?

Tags: git, git-svn

I have migrated my project's Subversion repository to Git, as per [How to migrate SVN with history to a new Git repository](/questions/79165/3972103#3972103). It worked very well except there is one disconnected branch due to some incorrect use of Subversion in our history. I'm not sure what the terminology is to describe the state of this branch. Here's what it looks like:

```
trunk: ...-A1--->        <---A3----A4-...

beta:         B1--B2--B3--B4----B5
```

From what I can tell, this is what happened. At revision *B1* a new "beta" branch was created by using *cp* instead of *svn cp*. At revisions *B4* and *A3* the entire repository was moved from */svnroot/project/orig* to */svnroot/project* (I don't think this is related to the problem but I mention it just in case). At *A4* the "beta" branch was merged back into trunk using *mv* and *rm* commands instead of *svn merge*.

How can I fix the Git repository history so that *B1* correctly branches from *A1* and *B5* merges back into *A4*? Note there are actually 75 revisions in the "beta" branch.

Comment: Do you know the exact base of the B1? Base means a commit from which the `cp` has been made.

Comment: I did a diff between the A1 and B1 trees. They are identical.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use grafts to create fake ancestry information. Create file `.git/info/grafts` and put something like this into it:

```
B1 A1
A4 A3 B5
```

But instead of the names of commits from your schema, put their full SHA1s. After this, make sure that the history looks the way you want it. If it does, you can make the grafts permanent by `git filter-branch --all`.

Of course, doing this rewrites history and it's a bad idea if anyone else already has a clone of your git repo.

Comment: Because the contents of B1 and A1 were identical they couldn't be grafted. I actually needed to graft B2 onto A1. Similarly I had to choose a later version to graft on to B5. Once I got the versions right this worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

`git checkout beta` - take the branch.

`git rebase A1` - move beta's commits on top of A1.

`git checkout A4` - switch to the A4

`git checkout -b new_merge_point` - create a temp branch for the merging

`git merge beta` - the merge. Could be conflicts?!.

`git checkout trunk` - back to trunk

`git rebase new_merge_point` reapply commits after A4 to the new merge point.

Comment: I think this is not what the OP wants. The merges were already done, trying to make them again will most likely only create lots of conflicts.

Comment: They could be resolved using the A4 as a reference... But yes, manually only, maybe just rewriting all files by A4 (or by soft reset). Looks like your solution is better, however I'm not sure I understand how does it work under the hood.

Comment: Ok, fortunately there is a way to do it better, using `ours` strategy: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/727994/git-skipping-specific-commits-when-merging - it's a way to record a merge with no changes.