# Git duplicate one branch to another

Tags: git, git-branch, git-rebase, git-cherry-pick

I have the following case :

```
                      K---L new-feature
                     /
            H---I---J---M dev-team1
           /
          E---F---G dev-main
         /
A---B---C---D master
```

And I want to move only the *new-feature* (K---L) branch in *dev-main* branch without (H---I---J) form *dev-team1*, however I want that *new-feature* (K---L) branch to remain as a separate branch.

Something like that :

```
                      K---L new-feature
                     /
            H---I---J---M dev-team1
           /
          E---F---G---K'---L' dev-main
         /
A---B---C---D master
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a job for [`cherry-pick`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick). Try

```
git checkout dev-main
git cherry-pick K
git cherry-pick L
```

You can also use the syntax described in the [`gitrevisions` documentation](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitrevisions.html) to specify a range of commits. In this example you want to merge commits reachable from the `new-feature` branch but not from the `dev-team1` branch, so you could write

```
git checkout dev-main
git cherry-pick dev-team1..new-feature
```

Also check this post about [how to merge a specific commit in Git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/881092/how-to-merge-a-specific-commit-in-git).

Comment: What if I have many commits like : K,L,N,O,P? I will write the command `git cherry-pick SHA` for each?

Comment: @EkKosmos, I have updated my answer with information about specifying `K` and `L` together, which may be useful if you have many commits to `cherry-pick`.

Answer (score 0):

you can merge ignore specifi commits H and I and merge the rest with dev-main from new-feature.

[git - skipping specific commits when merging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/727994/git-skipping-specific-commits-when-merging)