# Exclude specific commit from GitLab merge request

Tags: git, gitlab

I made a merge request containing about 8 commits.
To make the request easier to understand I want to remove 1 large commit from this merge request and send it in as a separate request.

Is this possible? If yes, how do I do this?

Comment: is that large commit the last commit?

Comment: @M.ah No it is the second.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [git - skipping specific commits when merging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/727994/git-skipping-specific-commits-when-merging)

Answer (score -2):

In this case, is better to edit the MR.