# Git: How do I pull a tagged revision into my fork?

Tags: git, github

I have a fork of a project on github where the main trunk was recently tagged.  I want to pull the code from the tagged revision into my fork.  How would I do that?

Comment: I'm a git newbie so I don't know all the terms yet... I want to merge the tagged code from the main trunk into my fork.  If that's what git calls a "merge", then yes :)

Comment: You might also want to check out this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/881092/how-to-merge-a-specific-commit-in-git

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Once you have the tag in local repository you can do something like

> `git merge tags/yourtag`

If you don't have the "trunk" tags locally, you can fetch it using

> `git fetch remote-url "refs/tags/*:refs/tags/*"`

Or by setting up the remote

> `git remote add upstream remote-url`

and fetching the stuff using

> `git fetch -t upstream`

I think, though, using

> `git remote update`

will have similar effect.

Comment: "Once you have the tag in local repository" - how do I do this (I'm really a git newbie).

What is the difference between "git merge" and "git fetch" and "git pull"?

Comment: @Jon: The second instruction here will fetch all the tags from the remote. Note that you can also do `git fetch --tags <remote-url>`.

Comment: @Jon: `git pull` is a combination of `git fetch` and `git merge`. It uses `git fetch` to retrieve information (branch positions, commits, etc) from the remote repository, then uses `git merge` to merge the appropriate remote branch into the current local branch. You can specify the remote branch by doing `git pull <remote-url> <branch>`, or you can specify both the default remote and branch to merge using the config parameters `branch.<branchname>.remote` and `branch.<branchname>.merge`.

Comment: It worth noting, though, that `git pull` operates on branches and therefore will merge in the tip of the branch and not the tag in question.
And to answer the question "how do I do this?" (get the local repository) — this is what everything beginning at "if you don't" deals with.

Comment: OK, I'm getting closer.  I have the remote reference set up.  Then I did "git fetch --tags myproject" and it got the tags.  But now how do I get the source code that was labeled with a specific tag?

Comment: If you're on the branch where you want to merge it in, just invoke the first command in my answer. If you just want to start off of the tag, you can do a `git checkout -b mynewbranch tags/thattag`.

Answer (score 13):

I may be projecting, but I think Jon's problem was the same as mine:

I forked someone else's project (on GitHub), and needed to point the *master* branch of my fork to a specific *tag* of their project, effectively ignoring all subsequent development. (Why? After that tag, their project dropped functionality that my fork depends on and must build on. So I'm pegged to that moment in history. Sad but true.)

In this example, the tag was called `0.6.3`. All I had to do was `cd` to my local clone (of my fork) and do

```
git reset --hard 0.6.3
git push --force
```

Then I verified on GitHub that my fork reflected the state of the code at their tag!