# Git: unable to update jQuery submodule to 1.11.3 or 1.12-stable

Tags: jquery, git

My git submodule is defined as

```
[submodule "protected/vendor/jquery-submodule"]
path = protected/vendor/jquery-submodule
url = git@github.com:jquery/jquery.git
```

Actually is checked out at tag 1.11.2.

Going on [official jQuery repo on Github](https://github.com/jquery/jquery) I see a branch `1.12-stable` and a tag `1.11.3`.

So I've executed, from inside the submodule folder

```
git fetch
git checkout tags/1.11.3
```

but It tell me that:

```
error: pathspec 'tags/1.11.3' did not match any file(s) known to git.
```

So I tried

```
git tag -l
```

and the new tag and the new branch I'm looking for are not listed.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: what happens when you cd into the submodule and type `git reset --hard 1472290917f17af05e98007136096784f9051fab` ? (that's the SHA of 1.11.3). Also, I'm guessing that `git fetch` actually brought in changes?

Comment: `git reset --hard 1472290917f17af05e98007136096784f9051fab` give me the error `fatal: Could not parse object '1472290917f17af05e98007136096784f9051fab'.
`

Comment: and when you typed `git fetch` from within the submodule, did it bring in any changes?

Comment: @HBHB: yes, it feteched 'something'. I don't remember what, but something was fetched out.Now I checked out `master`, then `git pull`, but again no new tags founds when listing tags... Amen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved with

```
git checkout origin/1.12-stable
```

I thinked it could work because when I did

```
git branch -a
```

(not the `-a`) it listed me this

```
* master
  origin/1.11-stable
  origin/1.12-stable
  origin/1.9-stable
  origin/1.x-master
  origin/2.1-stable
  origin/2.2-stable
  origin/HEAD
  origin/compat
  origin/delegation
  origin/killphp
  origin/master
  origin/standard-then
  origin/standard-then-tests
  origin/standard-then-tests-fixed
```

So I tried and it worked.

About the tag problem, I found the following command in [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1357086/git-how-do-i-pull-a-tagged-revision-into-my-fork)

```
git fetch git@github.com:jquery/jquery.git "refs/tags/*:refs/tags/*"
```

It told me

```
remote: Counting objects: 45, done.
remote: Total 45 (delta 23), reused 23 (delta 23), pack-reused 22
Unpacking objects: 100% (45/45), done.
From git@github.com:jquery/jquery
 * [new tag]         1.11.3     -> 1.11.3
 * [new tag]         2.1.4      -> 2.1.4
 * [new tag]         3.0.0-alpha1 -> 3.0.0-alpha1
 * [new tag]         3.0.0-alpha1+compat -> 3.0.0-alpha1+compat
```

And finally

```
git checkout 1.11.3
```

It worked !!!!