# Copy 1 commit from one branch (dev) to another (stable) with clean working dir

Tags: git, branch, commit, cherry-pick

I tried to understand [How to undo a commit and commit the changes into the other branch in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2100851/how-to-undo-a-commit-and-commit-the-changes-into-the-other-branch-in-git) but I don't think it has to be that hard. (Answer is using `branch -f` and `stash` and I don't think I need those.)

I was working in my dev branch. Had two different commits in dirty working dir. Commit all changes in two different commits. Last commit is WIP (so dev material). Second to last is done and should be copied to `stable` branch.

I imagine something like

```
$ git copy e87568fa stable
```

but I'm pretty sure that's not it.

Has cherry picking got something to do with it?

To be sure: I want the commit to stay on `dev`. So not `mv` it, but `cp` it.

I'm still baffled by all these GIT options and commands.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Go to the stable branch:

```
git checkout stable
```

Copy the desired commit to the current branch.

```
git cherry-pick e87568fa
```

You can now return to dev:

```
git checkout dev
```

Comment: I don't have a dirty working dir. Without the `stash` I just did exactly that (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1334027/git-working-on-multiple-branches/1340143#1340143). Perfect! Thanks. I might even remember this one =) and most definitely use it again.

Comment: I did the steps above, plus another line of :

`git cherry-pick {commit-ID}`
 
to move the `{commit-ID}` to the dev branch