# GIT: commit changes to old/safe branch while in new/dirty/dev branch without checking out or losing unstaged data

Tags: git, branch, commit, git-checkout

I created a new Branch before I started dev on something experimental. I usually forget that (which isn't a problem), but now I did it beforehand.
Since then I have updated 3 files.

- In 2 are only experimental changes that I DON'T want committed to the safe branch.
- In 1 are only safe (minor) changes that I definitely DO want committed to the safe branch. I'm fine with these last changes to be committed to the new branch as well (but rather not).

Is it possible - I'm sure it is - to (quickly) commit a few unstaged, uncommitted changes from my (dirty) working dir to an old, safe branch?

The only thing I can think of is switching branches (without checkout), commit the changes in 1 file and switch back, but I don't know what will have happened to the changes when switched back to the dirty branch (are they still there or did they 'vanish' due to the commit?)...

I'm sure GIT has something beautiful for this, but GIT has so much, I can't find the exact same thing.
(I've been using [this 'manual' for help](http://www-cs-students.stanford.edu/~blynn/gitmagic/ch04.html)  but I'm not sure the same exact thing is in there. If it is (and you're willing to scan the thing), please let me know, so I know next time to look harder.)

Thanks! For now I'll just keep a piece of paper handy with changes 'to commit to safe branch later'.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So your situation is

```
x--x--x (safe)
       \
        <a,b,c> (3 private evolutions in exp branch)
```

And you want to go to

```
x--x--x--a (a committed only in safe banch)
       \
        b,c (b and c commited in exp branch)
```

You could:

```
git add a
git commit -m        # in exp branch, gasp!
git stash save       # save the rest of the exp work in progress
git checkout master
git merge exp        # fast-forward merge

x--x--x--a (safe,exp)
          \
           [b,c] (stashed)

git branch -f exp HEAD~1  # reset branch exp to before 'a'
git checkout exp
git stash pop
git add -A
git commit -m "..."

x--x--x--a (a committed only in safe banch)
      \
        b,c (b and c commited in exp branch)
```

Comment: Since checkout doesn't touch modified files, wouldn't it be OK to just `checkout master; add a; commit; checkout exp` and carry on?  Assuming that the changes aren't staged.

Comment: @rlduffy: it should work. I always tends to be a little extra careful with those branch switches.

Comment: If ‘exp’ has commits beyond ‘safe’ (I could not decide this from the OP’s description) then you would not want to `git checkout safe && git merge exp` since it would pull in those other commits. If you are just going to cut ‘a’ off of ‘exp’ anyway, I would just cherry pick it onto ‘safe’ instead of merging it.

Comment: @Chris: but cherry-picking is bad, no? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/881092/how-to-merge-a-specific-commit-in-git/881112#881112 I always try to avoid cherry-picking.

Comment: @VonC: I would agree that cherry picking is often abused, but I would argue that this use is OK since you are dropping the original commit from ‘exp’ (in the end there is only one surviving commit with the “safe changes”: the one that is reachable from ‘safe’). The answer you linked to expresses concern for functional dependencies when cherry picking changes. Of course one still has to test that the “safe change” works on against ‘safe’/‘master’. That is always an issue whether cherry picking is involved or not. But the duplication issues usually inherent in cherry picking do not apply here.

Comment: @Chris: I completely agree (I overlooked the context of this exact question).

Comment: Actually, I want to save "a" (from "a committed only in safe banch") in both experimental and safe. I rather not commit anything in the exp branch, but it's fine if needed.

Comment: @Rudie: in that case, avoid "`git branch -f exp HEAD~1`" and the final  "`git add, git commit`", and you will be there.

Comment: You are the best and stackoverflow rules!

Answer (score 7):

There is no way to add a commit to an alternate branch with *git commit*. There are ways of using the low level “plumbing” commands to do exactly what you described, but the interface formed by those commands is not designed for interactive use<sup>1</sup>. There are certainly ways to do what you want; depending on the details of your changes and the contents of the branches involved it can be quite simple.

## The Easy Case: Just Use `git checkout`

When switching branches, *git checkout* will preserve uncommitted modifications or refuse to switch (unless you use `--force`, `--merge`, or `--conflict`). So, as long as your uncommitted changes only touch files that are the same in both HEAD (the current branch) and your destination branch, *git checkout* will leave those changes in the index and/or the working tree while switching branches. If your uncommitted changes satisfy this condition then you can do this:

```
git checkout safe-branch
git add -- files-with-safe-changes
git commit
git checkout -
```

<sup>You can also use `git add --patch` to stage and commit only some of the changes in the files.</sup>

After this, your “safe changes” will be a part of ‘safe‑branch’; switching back to your original branch will “leave them behind” (remember, *git checkout* only preserves uncommitted changes when switching branches).

If your other changes depend on the “safe changes” you may need to merge ‘safe‑branch’ into your working branch (or, depending on your workflow, rebase your working branch onto the new tip of ‘safe‑branch’). To do this you will have to stash your uncommitted changes (since both merge and rebase will refuse to function if there are uncommitted changes).

```
git stash save
git merge safe-branch
git stash pop --index
```

If your other changes do not depend on the “safe changes”, then you should probably not 
bother with a merge or rebase. Eventually you will merge these branches together (e.g. by merging them both into a ‘qa’ branch for pre-release testing), but there is no reason to merge them prematurely.

## Still Easy, but a Bit Risky: `git checkout -m`

If the first *git checkout* complains “You have local changes to `some‑file`; not switching branches.”, it means you have uncomitted changes to `some-file` and that the file is different in the tips of ‘safe‑branch’ and your current branch; you will need a different approach.

If you are confident that the changes would apply cleanly to the version of `some‑file` that is in ‘safe‑branch’, then you can use the `-m`/`--merge` option to tell *git checkout* to try to adapt the changes so that they apply to the files in ‘safe‑branch’. If the merge can not be done cleanly, then you will end up with a merge conflict and it may be difficult to recover your original changes (this is why I call it “risky”).

## Safe: `git stash` + `git checkout -m`

Since you really only want to move a subset of the changes back to ‘safe‑branch’, it may be better to focus on just those changes. One method is to use *git stash* to temporarily save your current changes so you do not have to drag all of them back to the ‘safe‑branch’ (and later drag some/most of them back to your working branch).

```
git stash save
git checkout stash -- files-with-save-changes
git checkout -m safe-branch
git commit
git checkout -
git stash pop --index
```

<sup>Other variations are possible. You can use `git checkout -p stash -- files` to pick out only some of the changes in those files. If there are no staged changes in the index, then you could first stage the “safe changes”, `git add -- files` (again, optionally with `-p`) , use `git stash save --keep-index`, switch branches (with merge), and then commit (i.e. replace the `git checkout stash -- files` with pre-staged “safe changes” and `git stash --keep-index`).</sup>

In this situation I consider `git checkout -m` to be safe because we used *git stash* to preserve a copy of the current changes; if the three-way merge attempt results in a hopeless mess, then you can easily abandon the idea of putting the “safe changes” on ‘safe‑branch’ and get back to work: switch back to your original branch and pop the stash (`git checkout -f - && git stash pop`).

Again, if your other changes depend on the “safe changes” then you will need to merge or rebase. You might as well do this before popping the stash (since you need a clean index and working tree to do the merge/rebase).

If you are not going to merge your working branch with (or rebase it onto) the ‘safe‑branch’ right away, then you will probably want to undo the “safe changes” after you pop the stash (the “safe changes” were saved in the original stash and you probably do not want to end up with commits that make the same changes from scratch in two different branches<sup>2</sup>). Once you have popped the stash, use `git checkout -- files-with-safe-changes` to revert those files back to versions at the tip of the working branch.

---

<sub><sup>1</sup>
The “plumbing” interface is designed for use in scripts. It would be cumbersome to use them directly on the command line. Early versions of *git commit* (and most other Git commands) were shell scripts that were based on this interface. They could still be written as shell scripts today, but the C versions are generally much faster.
The steps required to commit to an alternate branch are:

setup an alternate index based on the tree at the tip of the “safe branch”,

update the index with the “safe” changes (what if the changes can not be applied cleanly? it is nice to have a working tree to let the user resolve the conflicts),

write the index out as a tree object,

make a new commit object that points to the new tree and has the current tip of “safe branch” as its parent,

update the “safe branch” ref to point to the new commit.</sub>

<sub><sup>2</sup>
There is nothing technically wrong with committing your “safe changes” in two branches, but it is usually a good idea to make sure each change originates from only a single place.</sub>

Comment: I like the plumbing and the details. +1

Answer (score 0):

Since branching operations on GIT is so cheap, I would just use the following workflow:

- Create a new branch off your "experimental" branch
- commit whatever unstaged files required
- go back to master
- `cherrypick` whatever commits from your "experimental" & the new branch just created in step 1.
- go back to "experimental" branch