# Git pull till certain commit (tag)

Tags: git, git-pull

I have a clone of a remote repository. I updated its remote url to my own server. Then I did some commits and pushed them to my repository.
Now I need to pull some changes from the initial repository. From a specific branch.
I can do it by running

```
git pull http://example.com/repo.git example_branch
```

This will pull every new commit from `example_branch` (and actually I will get a dev version). But this `example_branch` has tags. And I need to stop pulling at a certain one (get a stable release in my case).
How can I do that?

**UPD** Finally I came up with:

```
git remote add example http://example.com/repo.git
git fetch
git merge tag_name
```

Comment: I think you're trying to solve the wrong problem. Why would you want to pull only up to a specific commit?

Comment: Well, if I pull all commits from a branch, I will get a dev version. But I need a stable release.

Comment: see also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31462683/git-pull-till-a-particular-commit/64558798

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`git pull`is just a `git fetch` followed by a `git merge`. So you can easily do a `git fetch` and then merge the desired commit / tag.

Comment: Why not write the commands for doing this instead of just saying you can easily do this?

Answer (score 2):

A git repository can supports multiple remote.

In your case, you need to add a second remote (with your old server):

```
git remote add old_server http://example.com/repo.git
```

Then you can simply fetch from it:

```
git fetch old_server
```

At last, [merge the specific commit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/881092/how-to-merge-a-specific-commit-in-git) you want to grab into your project.