# git:How can I apply commits from old version on a new version of source-code

Tags: git

I am working on an open-source project that uses Mercurial.

I made a git repo inside the source directory and now have about 40-odd commits.

The project released a new version of the source-code and I now wish to apply the commits I made selectively.

What I mean is, among the various directories that exist, I want to replace only the src directory while ignoring all the updated library directories (Which I have not modified in any commit anyway)

Everytime I try a `git checkout -b <branch> -t <remote/branch>` I get an error saying I need to either move or remove tonnes of existing files

How can I go about doing this?

Comment: you could try to `git stash && git checkout -b <branch> -t <remote/branch> && git stash apply`

Comment: I'm a little confused, how do you have a "remote branch" if you created the git repo yourself?  If you `git clone`d it from somewhere, sure...  Did you use some conversion tool to convert from an hg repo to a git repo?

Answer (score 0):

`git cherry-pick <commit>` will apply commit to the current repository.
Use `git stash` before this commang and `git stash pop` after this command, if you have any unstaged changes.

Comment: This will also make `git merge` impossible since commit IDs will differ..wouldn't it?

merge is a very useful functionality to have..could there be a non-intrusive way of achieving this?

Comment: @user1761555 Why would it make `merge` impossible?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/881092/how-to-merge-a-specific-commit-in-git/881112#881112 ..I may have misunderstood