# Accidentally branched off of the wrong branch, and when I want to merge into the master I have to merge both branches

Tags: git, version-control, merge

So I created a branch off of another branch I was already creating, and now when I try to merge the branches into master, I have run into the situation where I have to merge both branches.

Here is a diagram

> Master->
>
> > ```
> >  ->Branch 1  -> Branch 2
> > ```

I want to be able to merge just the changes on branch 2 onto master without having to merge the changes on Branch 1 if that makes sense. I looked into reset and revert, but it seems like these things will delete all the changes I made with branch 2. Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Assuming you meant `git`, you want `git rebase --onto`.

Answer (score 103):

Try git rebase --onto with the following syntax:

To put branch2's changes on to the master without including branch1's

```
git rebase --onto master branch1 branch2
```

Relevant output from `git help rebase`:

> Here is how you would transplant a topic branch based on one branch to another, to
>   pretend that you forked the topic branch from the latter branch, using `rebase --onto`.
>
> First let’s assume your *topic* is based on branch *next*. For example, a feature 
>   developed in *topic* depends on some functionality which is found in *next*.
>
> ```
>               o---o---o---o---o  master
>                    \
>                     o---o---o---o---o  next
>                                      \
>                                       o---o---o  topic
> ```
>
> We want to make *topic* forked from branch *master*; for example, because the functionality
>   on which *topic* depends was merged into the more stable *master* branch. 
>   We want our tree to look like this:
>
> ```
>               o---o---o---o---o  master
>                   |            \
>                   |             o'--o'--o'  topic
>                    \
>                     o---o---o---o---o  next
> ```
>
> We can get this using the following command:
>
> ```
> git rebase --onto master next topic
> ```

Keep in mind the risks and pitfalls of rebasing, mentioned here:
 http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Branching-Rebasing

Comment: I'm here because I did the same thing as OP. I.e. I accidentally branched my local features/feature1 as features/feature2. And should have braned develop as features/feature2. It looks like rebase --onto will do what I want, but should I check-out one of the three branches before running rebase? And I suppose I need to commit my change to features/feature2 first??

Answer (score 14):

One way to do it is, use `cherry-pick`. Do a `git log branch2` and find the commit id's you want and then switch to `master` branch using `git checkout master` then use `git cherry-pick <commit_id>`

Refer to this post for more details

[How to merge a specific commit in Git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/881092/how-to-merge-a-specific-commit-in-git)