# git - how to commit a bug fix, when my branch is ahead?

Tags: git

Maybe my question is not well-formed.
The situation is this: we have 3 public branches: dev, qa, master.
I need to commit an urgent fix to the `master`, but the `dev` and the `qa` branches are already **ahead** of the `master` by a few commits.

What is the **cleanest** method to make a patch, and apply it to the `master` branch, as well as to all the branches?

EDIT:
Since many comments suggested cherry-picking, I would like to emphasize that I haven't committed the fix yet. I want to avoid cherry-picking, so if there's a better way of doing it, I would be happy to hear (maybe commit the fix on the `master` and then rebase `qa` and `dev`)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to merge a specific commit in git](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/881092/how-to-merge-a-specific-commit-in-git)

Comment: On which branch ist your commit for the fix ?

Comment: @rangalo I haven't written the bug fix yet. I will write it wherever it will require the least mess in merging.

Comment: @OneOfOne thanks for the comment, but I don't like cherry picking. So since I haven't committed the fix yet, I'm interested to know if there's a way to do that without cherry-picking. Maybe committing to the master and then rebasing the qa and dev branches?

Comment: Look at the answer by Gergo Erdosi. It would be best for you to start a hotfix branch from the last stable master and after the hotfix merge it back to master and dev. Search for hotfixes in the following page http://danielkummer.github.io/git-flow-cheatsheet/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a hotfix branch that is merged off from master and then merged back into master and develop. You can read more about hotfix branches [here](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/):

> May branch off from: master Must merge back into: develop and master
>   Branch naming convention: hotfix-*
>
> Hotfix branches are very much like release branches in that they are
>   also meant to prepare for a new production release, albeit unplanned.
>   They arise from the necessity to act immediately upon an undesired
>   state of a live production version. When a critical bug in a
>   production version must be resolved immediately, a hotfix branch may
>   be branched off from the corresponding tag on the master branch that
>   marks the production version.
>
> The essence is that work of team members (on the develop branch) can
>   continue, while another person is preparing a quick production fix.

Comment: Thanks. I tried this method. I created a hotfix branch from the master, fixed, committed and merged into the master. Now i'm trying to merge the hotfix branch into the qa branch but I get lots of conflicts (as I stated in my question, qa branch is ahead of master). Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

[cherry-pick](http://think-like-a-git.net/sections/rebase-from-the-ground-up/cherry-picking-explained.html) an individual commit from dev to master.