# Merging a commit from one branch to main branch

Tags: git

When I am reading about merge, I see branch merges or merges with cherry-picking, but is there another way to merge one commit into a main branch. Here is my scenario.

I have a Mainline Branch where I have some changes. In the morning, I create a new branch TestBr off of MainLine and work on my own commits. When I commit something C1 in the afternoon, I want to merge C1 into Mainline. Shouldn't git merge command solve this without using cherry-picking. Or is get merge only for branch merges.

Thanks.

Comment: `git cherry-pick` is what you want. `git merge` can't deal with commits.. only branches.  This is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/881092/how-to-merge-a-specific-commit-in-git

Comment: Thank you. I did read all those qns before asking this. I was trying to see if git merge can do this without cherry picking.

Comment: then the answer is no `:)`  Do you have an issue using `git cherry-pick`?

Comment: Not in general. I am a newbie to git so in the process of figuring it out I was wondering how pull requests work. Do they do merge on specific commit? Hence the question. I wish I had a someone whom I can ping on IM and ask all my questions. :) Thanks for looking.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind bringing over all of the commits from your branch `TestBr` then `git merge` will work.  If you have other commits (e.g. `C2`, `C3`, etc) and only want commit `C1`, use `git cherry-pick`.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I was looking at one commit at a time.