# Maintaining CrossPlatform Source code with git

Tags: git, github, bitbucket

I am trying to learn git and , I need help in creating a new repo for my new game in unity.

I have developed a game on unity for which now I want to maintain a cross-platform specific code. Since there will be specific code and features for android & iOS so what I was thinking to do is to keep my WebPlayerVersion of unity as a master repo and creating different branches for android & iOS so that I can add features on the respective branches without merging it with master.

Now say If I change something in core gameplay on my master branch and I want it on my android & iOS branch then how do i tackle that

One thing I can do is everytime I change something on my master branch then I have to go and individually merge that code with some visual merge tool for respective branches but thinking at the bigger level its going to be difficult so is there any alternate way for this

Or any other good alternative solution with git for this particular scenario

Comment: Why such irrelevant tagging for pure Git-question?!

Comment: Read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/881092/how-to-merge-a-specific-commit-in-git

Answer (score 0):

> If I change something in core gameplay on my master branch and I want it on my android & iOS branch then how do i tackle that

**Merge branches** with ordinary merge or just changeset(s) with cherry-pick

Comment: What? You want to merge a branch that makes the program for android into the iOS branch? What are you talking about here? Since the branches separate platforms, they must remain diverged.