# GIT workflow complicated

Tags: git, version-control, merge, branch, git-workflow

Its been very difficult to manage the git.
My issue:

Lets say i have a project, and has branches called "**master**" and "**develop**"
and say **Mary** works on a feature branch called "**feature-payment**" (this branch is created from master),
**mary** finishes of the work on "**feature-payment**" branch then merges and pushes to develop branch.

Then **john** pulls the **develop** branch in his local. then he wants to do some css part. since he doesn't have the feature branch, he has to work on **develop** branch. then he makes changes and finishes the styling and pushes the develop branch.

When the feature is ready to made live, **mary** merges her branch to **master**, but john can't merge **develop** to **master**, since there are multiple features on develop branch which are not made live.
In this case what should be done guys ??
Please help guide me with branching workflow .. this issue happens to me everytime. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can merge specific commits from a branch without merging the entire branch (see here : [How to merge a specific commit in Git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/881092/how-to-merge-a-specific-commit-in-git))

However, a more appropriate solution would be to merge from the feature branch into master once the code has been reviewed. The purpose of your develop branch is confusing in this context, as it seems to have changes that are both ready for production and not. To me, it seems like your issue could be resolved by just merging feature branches into master once the changes are reviewed sufficiently, instead of into this "middle" develop branch.

Answer (score 0):

1. Branches cost nothing, there is no reason for John to develop directly in develop, he can create his own branch.
2. I think the general problem you have is that you have things in develop that you don't want to release. Only merge things into develop that should get released the next time. Keep other features in their branches if needed.
3. As you have the problem now: check git cherry-pick to only merge single commits to master.

Answer (score 0):

With current situation i would handle it by create another branch (release) from master and use git cherry-pick for picking commit you will needed.

For future use git workflow designed by atlassian 
https://www.atlassian.com/pt/git/workflows#!workflow-gitflow

If you have simple scenario then release branch is not mandatory for every release

And force john to use feature branches :)