# Git merge commits selectively

Tags: git, git-merge, rebase, merge-conflict-resolution

I have a question about Git that I've never had to do, so I would like to learn!

In my project I branched off `master` a while back; it is essentially a rewrite of the entire codebase, so let's call it `rewrite`. In the time that I have been working on `rewrite` I have also made and deployed some significant changes to `master`. Now that my rewrite is coming to a close, I want to bring it up to speed with all the changes made on master since I started the branch.

Usually I would do something like `git checkout rewrite && git rebase master` and then solve the conflicts as they arise, but this time around  I can guarantee every commit with have a conflict since the codebase is entirely different.

**tl;dr** What I am wondering is how I would go about taking each commit on `master` and one-by-one merging them into `rewrite`, so I could do it at my own pace and possibly out of order if need be.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to merge a specific commit in Git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/881092/how-to-merge-a-specific-commit-in-git)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `git cherry-pick` command to put specific commit to your branch.

You can also use `gitk --all` to see all commits and select which commit you want to cherry-pick interactively to your branch.

Comment: For some extra insurance, you can `git checkout rewrite && git checkout -b rewriteMerge` which will give you an identical branch to start and perform your cherry picking on. That way, if anything, at any point, goes awry, it's a little easier to get back to where you were. There are of course other methods (such as resets and later on creating a new branch based on the final `rewrite` commit shaVal), but this way gives you something tangible and accessible by simply changing branches.