# Git get changes from a master brach into dev

Tags: git, github, version-control, merge

I have two branches now `master` and `dev`.
They are parallel. 
I have added several commits to my master branch and now I need just to get all these changes in the `dev` branch, but do not have a copy of master, because I have some source files in the `dev` branch.

And branches should be parallel as they are now, without merging and other stuff.

How can I do this ?

Comment: Export the diff patches from the master branch and apply them to the dev branch. https://coderwall.com/p/yeh5tw/how-to-create-and-apply-a-patch-with-git

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to merge a specific commit in Git](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/881092/how-to-merge-a-specific-commit-in-git)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to **apply changes from a commit** on `master` branch to `dev` branch, you can use `git cherry-pick <the commit from master>`.

If you want to **apply changes from a serial of commits** on `master` branch to `dev` branch, you can use `git rebase --onto dev <start commit from master> <end commit from master>`.

**Note:** the `start commit` is not including to rebase, but the `end commit` is included. So the range is `commit next to start commit`~`end commit`.