# Cherry-pick to specific commit from other branch

Tags: git, version-control

Is this possible ? Cherry picking from other branch into specific commit of master branch. 
For eg: 
Say, I've two branch:

```
 -> master : <commit1>, <commit2>, <commit3>
 -> test: <c1>, <c2>, <c3>, <c4>
```

And now I want to cherry pick a commit (eg: `<c3>`) from `test` branch to a `<commit2>` in master branch.

**Edit**: I know it can be done via `rebase` command, but can it be done via `cherry-pick` only?

Comment: Do you mean you want to add the changes from a specific commit in another branch to an existing commit in the master branch?

Comment: yes, but via cherry-pick if possible because I heard cherry-pick is low level tool of rebase command.

Comment: Why are you against using rebase? It's the correct tool for the job.

Comment: I'm currently learning git, so right now I just want to keep my toolset small. That's why I'm avoiding rebase as it has more options.

Comment: I understand that the original question refers to perform cherry-pick, nevertheless I found this answer on a similar question very good, at least to have an alternative perspective of how this situation could (should ?) be handled/resolved: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62402568/1971003

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You have a fundamental error in how you are thinking Git works.

> Is this possible ? Cherry picking from other branch into specific commit of master branch.

No: Git *cannot* change *any* commit.  You can *add new commits*, and you can *copy* an existing commit to make a new commit from it, i.e., add a new commit that is a copy of an existing commit (with, presumably, at least one thing different in the copy).  The latter is what `git cherry-pick` does.

You can also change the specific commit hash ID any branch *name* remembers for you.

#### Drawing branches

> Say, I've two branch:
>
> ```
> -> master : <commit1>, <commit2>, <commit3>
> -> test: <c1>, <c2>, <c3>, <c4>
> ```

This is not a good way to draw branches.  Here is a better way:

```
...--D--E--F--G   <-- master
      \
       H--I--J--K   <-- test
```

Commit `E` here corresponds to your `<commit1>`, I just used single letters to keep them shorter.  Similarly, `F` is like your `<commit2>`, and `J` is like your `<c3>`.  I also included another earlier commit, `D`, from which both the branches extend, to suggest that there are probably earlier commits before both `E` and `H`.

Note that each commit remembers its *parent* commit: the parent of `G` is `F`, so we say that `G` "points back" to `F`.  `F` points back to `E`, which points back to `D`, and so on.  Likewise, commit `K` points back to `J` which points back to `I` which points back to `H`.  Note that `H`, which is only on branch `test`, *also* points back to `D`.

(Commit `D` is particularly interesting: it is on *both branches*.  It is also what Git calls the *merge base* of the two branches.  But that's not our concern here; it's just an interesting side note, that in Git, commits can be on *more than one* branch simultaneously.)

The branch *names*, in this case `master` and `test`, each point to one specific commit.  Here the name `master` points to commit `G`, and the name `test` points to commit `K`.  This is how we decide which commits are on which branches: we start, as Git does, using the branch names to find the branch *tip* commits.  From those tip commits, we—or Git—work backwards: we go from any one commit, to its parent commit, and then to that commit's parent, and so on.  This process stops only when we get tired of following parents (e.g., quit out of `git log`), or are told to stop—we won't see that here though—or we hit a *root* commit, which is a commit with *no* parents.  The very first commit you ever make in a repository is a root commit, since there is no earlier commit it could use as a parent.  (It's possible to make extra root commits, but again we won't see that here.)

#### Cherry-picking commits

> And now I want to cherry pick a commit (eg: `<c3>`) from test branch ***to a `<commit2>`*** in master branch.

You *can* cherry-pick a commit, but the part I put in bold italics ("to a commit") is nonsense.  Cherry-picking means *copying* a commit.  The copy is a *new* commit, which you would normally add on to a branch.

Since your `<c3>` is my `J`, let's see what happens if you use:

```
git checkout master
git cherry-pick test~1
```

The first step gets you "on" branch `master`, i.e., new commits you add now will be added to `master`, by making the name `master` point to them.

The second step identifies commit `J` by walking back one step from the tip of `test`.  The name `test` identifies commit `K`: a branch name "means" the tip commit of that branch.  The `~1` suffix means "count back one parent", so we move from commit `K` to commit `J`.  That is the commit we ask Git to copy.

We'll ignore the exact mechanics of doing this copy, for the moment, and just look at the result.  Git makes a *new* commit that is "like" `J`; let's call this new commit `J'`.  There are several differences between the original `J` and the new copy `J'`, and the important one for the moment is that the *parent* of the copy is the existing tip of `master`, i.e., commit `G`.  So `J'` points back to `G`.

Once the copy is done, and the new `J'` is stored permanently, Git updates `master` to point to the new commit we just made:

```
...--D--E--F--G--J'  <-- master
      \
       H--I--J--K   <-- test
```

Note that no existing commit is affected.  This is because it's literally *impossible* to change any existing commit.

#### Rebase

> I know it can be done via `rebase` command ...

It *can't* and this really does matter.  What rebase does is not *modify* commits.  Instead, it makes copies—possibly a whole lot of copies.

Let's consider the case where you have the `D-E-F-G` sequence on `master` and you'd like to copy `J` and insert it *after* `F` but *before* `G`.  That is, you would like to get this, even though it's impossible:

```
...--D--E--F--J'-G   <-- master
      \
       H--I--J--K   <-- test
```

The reason it's impossible is that `G` *cannot be changed*, and `G` already points back to `F`.  But what if we did this instead:

```
             J'-G'  <-- new-master
            /
...--D--E--F--G   <-- old-master
      \
       H--I--J--K   <-- test
```

In other words, what if we copy `J` to `J'` on a *new* `new-master` branch, with `J'` coming after `F`, and then copy `G` to `G'`, with `G'` coming after `J'`?  We *can* do this with `git cherry-pick`, we just have to cherry pick *two* commits, `J` first, and then `G`, onto a new branch:

```
git checkout -b new-master master~1    # make the new-master branch at F
git cherry-pick test~1                 # copy J to J'
git cherry-pick master                 # copy G to G'
```

And, suppose once we have done that, we *erase* the old `master` name entirely and just call the new one `master`, like this:

```
             J'-G'  <-- master
            /
...--D--E--F--G   [abandoned]
      \
       H--I--J--K   <-- test
```

Now if we stop drawing the abandoned original `G`, and draw `master` in a straight line, it *looks like* we've inserted `J'` between `F` and `G` ... but we have not: we instead copied `G` to `G'`.

The `git rebase` command is, essentially, an automated, high-powered "cherry pick a lot of commits" command, followed by some branch name moving-about at the end.

#### Why all this matters

This only matters sometimes, but when it does matter, it matters a *lot*.

Let's say we start with this, which is a lot like before except there's another branch too:

```
...--D--E--F--G   <-- master
      \        \
       \        L   <-- develop
        \
         H--I--J--K   <-- test
```

Now let's copy `J` to `J'`, putting that after `F`, and then copy `G` to `G'` with `J'` as `G'`'s parent, and make the name `master` remember the hash ID for new commit `G'`.  (This is the same rebase-with-copy we did before; we just have this extra `develop` branch.)

```
             J'-G'  <-- master
            /
...--D--E--F--G
      \        \
       \        L   <-- develop
        \
         H--I--J--K   <-- test
```

Now let's re-draw this so that there's less weirdness in the layout:

```
...--D--E--F--J'-G'  <-- master
      \     \
       \     G--L   <-- develop
        \
         H--I--J--K   <-- test
```

Even though we got Git to "forget" the original commit `G` on `master` in favor of the shiny new `G'` that has `J'` as its parent, the original `G` still there on branch `develop`.  In fact, now it looks as though `G` was *always* on `develop` and we probably cherry-picked it into `master` from there.

The key point here is that **you can copy commits and forget that the originals were there, but if so, you must be sure you *really* forget them.**  If those originals are known elsewhere—through another branch in your own repository, or (worse) `git push`ed to another repository—you have to get all the other users to use the new versions, if that's what you want.  You *cannot change the originals*, you can only copy them to new ones and get every user to switch to the new ones.

Comment: Upvoted, not only because you've detailed answer. But you also actually explained the reason why I'm thinking incorrectly.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use `git cherry-pick <commit from test branch>` to apply changes to `master` branch.

To cherry pick a commit from test branch to a commit (not the latest) on master branch, you can use below way:

```
git checkout <a commit on master you want to cherry pick>
git cherry-pick <a commit from test branch>
git rebase --onto HEAD <the commit you used in step1> master
```

Comment: I don't want to apply changes to head of the master branch. I just want to apply to specific commit in master branch via cherry-pick

Comment: You can checkout to the commit firstly,and then cherry-pick a comment,then use git rebase --onto HEAD <the commit you checked out > master

Comment: `git rebase --onto HEAD` is probably not needed if you did `git checkout my-branch` in the first step. In fact, if you do `git rebase --onto HEAD my-branch`, then it does nothing.

Answer (score 1):

You are going to re-write your repository history, which is not something that is recommended.

- First, create a new branch at the necessary commit in master branch.
- Checkout new branch.
- Cherry pick the necessary commit from test
  branch into new branch.
- Checkout master branch.
- Rebase master branch
  into new branch.

You will have to force push master branch if you need to push the master branch to a remote repository. If others have checked in the master branch, their master branch will get invalidated by doing this.

Comment: The point is I don't want to use rebase, just cherry-pick. If I want to do that, then your 2 point is not necessary.

Comment: @AshishRawat: unfortunately, you *must* use a temporary branch ("checkout the new branch", step 2) because Git only adds new commits to branches. You can use what Git calls a "detached HEAD" to do this—that's how `git rebase` does it—to avoid needing a temporary branch *name*, but you still have a temporary branch.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change an existing commit, you can use `rebase` in combination with `cherry-pick`.

```
GIT_SEQUENCE_EDITOR='sed -i s/^pick/edit/' git rebase -i <commit2>
git cherry-pick -n <c3>
git commit --amend -C HEAD
git rebase --continue
```

This first runs rebase to select the commit on master for editing. Then it applies the changes from the other commit, modifies the commit on master, and finishes the rebase. Of course this doesn't actually *change* the commit, but it will create a new commit that has the changes from both `<commit2>` and `<c3>`.

The use of `GIT_SEQUENCE_EDITOR` just avoids having to manually select the single commit for editing when starting the rebase.