# How to merge a previous commit of one file from another branch

Tags: git, github, merge

I thought I could do this but then I started typing out the command and I was like lets back up and make sure I do this right!

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You can't merge single commits, you merge branches. Does the commit in question contain changes to other files as well?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to merge a specific commit in Git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/881092/how-to-merge-a-specific-commit-in-git)

Answer (score 0):

Get the commit id, switch to branch where you want to merge it and do cherry-pick, as follows:

```
git checkout another-branch
git cherry-pick commit-id-hash
```