# What are the perils of cherry picking in git between two branches A and B if I am never going to merge between them?

Tags: git, cherry-pick, git-cherry-pick

I have read the excellent series of posts by Raymond Chen titled [Stop cherry-picking, start merging](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20180323-01/?p=98325)

And I totally understand that cherry-picking is evil **if we are going to merge the branches afterwards**.

But suppose I never merge the two branches. Are there any perils of cherry-picking in this case?

Comment: Short answer: no, none.

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly "none", but low risk.

The only issue remains to pick up a change depending on another change that is *not* cherry-picked: the resulting merge would not work in the destination branch while it was working on the source branch.
That is called "[ignoring functional dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/a/881112/6309)".