# How to list git tags containing commit that was cherry-picked

Tags: git, tags, git-commit, git-cherry

I'm trying to find out how I can list all the tags that contains a given commit including those that were cherry-picked.

For example:

- I have a commit `abcd1234`, which has been merged into the `master` branch.
- This gives me a *merge commit* with hash `a1b2c3d4`
- I create a tag at this point named *release-1.0*

At this point, I can use `git tag --contains abcd1234` OR `git tag --contains a1b2c3d4`. Both of these commands will list the tag **release-1.0**

Now:

- I created a hot-fix branch from *release-1.0* tag
- I have a new *merge commit* on the master with the hash `xyz789`
- I cherry-pick this commit onto the **hot-fix** branch
- I tag this **hot-fix** branch as *release-1.1* and delete the branch

How can I get a list of all the tags that contains commit `xyz789`? In this case, it should show that this commit is available in:

- release-1.1

Comment: Why on earth are you cherry-picking a commit onto a branch you're about to delete? And a merge commit (empty of changes) at that? Maybe describe what you tried to achieve by these two last steps, when you could have been done after merging hot-fix in master and tagging your xyz789 commit with 1.1 tag.

Comment: The "hot-fix" branch doesn't need to be kept around once it's been released. Plus, it will be different when `release-2.0` comes out. The reason for cherry-picking merge-commit is because the workflow involves creating a merge commit when changes are merged into master. So, when certain "merge request" needs to be released as a hot fix, the merge commit is cherry-picked into the hot-fix branch.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that `release-1.1` *does not* contain commit `xyz789` (which is also not a valid hash ID, but never mind that :-) ).  Cherry-picking creates a new, different commit, with a new, different hash ID.

Rather than attempting to track which commits are copies of which other commits—this is possible; see the `-x` argument to `git cherry-pick`—it's better to apply the hot-fix commit as a branch, whether temporary or not, that gets created right after the commit(s) where the problem first occurs.  This commit can then be merged to multiple different branches.  See [What are the perils of cherry picking in git between two branches A and B if I am never going to merge between them?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52656588/1256452) and follow the links to Raymond Chen's blog posts.

Comment: You're right that cherry-picking creates a new commit. I didn't mention it in the post to keep it simple. In my case `git cherry-pick -x` is already being used. It appends the line to the message to specify where this was cherry-picked from. But, if I wanted to track where the "original" commit (in this case `xyz789`) has gone into, I don't know of a straight-forward way to find out that info.

Comment: `git branch --contains` will show that `master` contains it, since you merged it into `master`.

Comment: That's true, but the question is which releases contains the changes from commit `xyz789`. The `master` is always under development and all fixes and features will exist in master.