# Remove commit messages of feature branch from master branch after feature branch is merged and pushed

Tags: git, github

We have a practice of squashing all commits of feature branch before merging it in master branch so that we will have one commit of feature branch in master. But accidentally I merged the feature branch into master without squashing. Is there anything than can be done to to resoove the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you haven't made any commit on master after merging that feature branch, you could:

- hard reset in your local repo `master` to the commit before that merge
- squash and merge your feature branch
- force push `master` and notify any other member working on that repository, for them to reset their own local `master` branch to that new `master` HEAD.

That is:

```
git reset --hard <SHA1 before merge>
# squash+merge
git push --force
```

> I have 2 commits in `master` branch after the merge.
>   But those where my commits so I know what files I have changed.
>   Can I still reset my branch from the above method and then commit the next two changes again?

Yes: they [can be cherry-picked](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1994491/6309) and replayed on top of the new `master` HEAD.

Again, once you force push (`git push --force`) that new branch history, you need to make sure any other collaborator is aware the history change, and reset his/her own local `master` branch accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have 2 commits in master branch after the merge. But those where my commits so I know what files I have changed. Can I still reset my branch from the above method and then commit the next two changes again?

Comment: @BhawnaJoshi Yes: you can actually cherry-pick (https://stackoverflow.com/a/1994491/6309, https://stackoverflow.com/a/881112/6309) those two commits once your reset + (quash,merge) is done. Just make a note of those two SHA1 before starting the process.