# append branch commits with git

Tags: git, git-rebase

I would like to append the commits of another branch to my current branch:

```
      A---B---C feat_A*
     /
o---o---o---o master
     \
      D---E---F feat_B


      A---B---C---D'--E'--F' feat_A*
     /
o---o---o---o master
     \
      D---E---F feat_B
```

However, doing a `git rebase feat_B` results in `D---E---F---A'--B'--C'`.

Another option would be to do

```
git checkout feat_B
git rebase feat_A
```

which results in the correct order `A---B---C---D'--E'--F'` but then these commits are in feat_B instead of feat_A.

How can I get git-rebase to append the commits of another branch onto the current one?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to merge a specific commit in Git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/881092/how-to-merge-a-specific-commit-in-git)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The operation could be easy without rebase, just cherry-pick the range you need :

```
git checkout feat_A
git cherry-pick ..feat_B
```

where `..feat_B` is an implicit `HEAD..feat_B`, meaning "every commit from `feat_B` which is not already reachable from `HEAD`".

Comment: I didn't know you could cherry-pick a range. Sadly there is not an interactive version of cherry-pick. I had to omit and edit some commits by hand.

Answer (score 1):

The `git cherry-pick <commit>` command allows you to take a single commit (from whatever branch) and, essentially, rebase it in your working branch.