# Git fetch differences as local change

Tags: git

Is there a way to fetch differences from a different branch or commit without introducing them to your local history? Just fetching all the changes as unstaged code?

For example

Branch1:

```
(HEAD) abc1 : added file A.txt
```

Branch2:

```
(HEAD) abc2 : added file B.txt
 |
abc1 : added file A.txt
```

so at `Branch1` i want to fetch all the differences from `Branch2` without adding them to `Branch1` history. As a result I expect to have `A.txt` from commit `abc1` and an unstaged file `B.txt`

Comment: Check this out, https://stackoverflow.com/a/881112/1559611, you can use `git cherry-pick`

Answer (score 1):

git checkout command  is able to pick a single file (or many files) from specific version without changing a branch. Note that command git checkout is kind of Swiss army knife tool and is able to do many stuff.

In your case it should be:

```sh
git checkout branch2 -- B.txt
```

This should create file `B.txt` in staged state.

Comment: I didn't downvote but here OP is asking how to get diff changes in the Branch 1 itself, not checkout Branch 2, which in my view is a bizzare requirement

Comment: This is some explanation, but question is a bit fuzzy. Last sentence says: `As a result I expect to have A.txt from commit abc1 and an unstaged file B.txt`. And part `fetch all the differences` doesn't necessary means he just need to see a diff.

Comment: My guess is as good as yours until and unless OP provides a clarity, in my view we can do a better job using `cherry-pick`

Comment: Question says "fetching all the changes as unstaged code"; so that's actually pretty clear, even if the wording is a little awkward.  `checkout` isn't a bad answer, but it shoudl be clarified that this makes them *staged* changes, wehreas ideally OP asked for unstaged.  Doesn't matter in the example (can just unstage the file), but might matter in a real usage.