# Git: Ignoring certain commits when pushing

Tags: git

I'd like to have some modifications that are private to my fork. How do I go about doing this?

There's a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1789017/git-push-a-single-commit) about pushing a single commit, and the answer is to cherry-pick the commits you want to push from a private branch and put them on the main branch. However, I would like something more along the lines of ignoring a certain commit when pushing.

Comment: If this is really necessary, then I'd have to ask if these items should be part of your repository?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If those commits are part of commits not yet pushed, you can:

- reoder them ([rebase --interactive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2302736/trimming-git-checkins-squashing-git-history/2302947#2302947)) to put them as the most recent commits
  (actually, if they are sequential, you can [`rebase --onto` another branch altogether](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2369426/how-to-move-certain-commits-to-another-branch-in-git/2369516#2369516))
- make a branch "private" to mark the tip if the current "dev" branch
- reset that dev branch to the last commit before those private ones
- push dev branch.

So the solution still involves a "private" branch in the process, but more importantly it is about isolating (hence the branch) the part of history which is not made to be published, ending up with a clearer "public" history for you to publish (push).

Comment: But this would mean that each time I wanted to do a push, I would have to run through this process again. Is there a way to automate this?

Comment: @int3: as long as you keep separate your private commits (made on the private branch) and your public commits (on the public branch), you can: 1/ rebase your private branch on top of your public branch anytime you want to have a full environment. 2/ push only your public branch. So you commit as usual except than when a commit is made on the public branch, a rebase of private (on top of the updated public branch) must be done in order for you to go on with a complete workspace.

Answer (score 0):

why not make a fork of the main branch and ask the owner of that branch to make a pull? Kind of like github style?