# push from git/svn repo into a git/branch at specific commit

Tags: git, git-svn, git-branch

At one time, the SVN repo was cloned at commit c75e75c. One team worked on git/master, another team worked on SVN.

- We are using git-svn on the svn repo.
- I could merge `svn/trunk` into `git/master` but this would terribly
  awful. So I prefer to push  all the commits after c75e75c into the `branch/app_v2`
- The git/branch is simply a copy of svn/trunk after commit c75e75c.

[image]

Tried with `git push <remotename> <commit SHA>:<remotebranchname>` [How can I pushing specific commit to a remote, and not the previous commits?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3230074/git-pushing-specific-commit) . I created a remote branch/app_v2. But the commits SHA on git-svn and git repo are not the same. Even they have a common history.

How to push a a range of commits ( between c75e75c and HEAD) and push to remote branch ( branch/app_v2 ) ?

Comment: I don't fully understand your question. Subversion does not use hashes. Creating a new branch on the remote should work the way you did (it must have the same commit hashes as your original branch)

Comment: I said I use git-svn, so the svn repo's commits are hashes. The git-svn repo is actually the sub folder /trunk of a bigger svn repo. Maybe that's why the commit SHA are not the same.

Comment: cd <git-svn-repo> && 
git branch branch/app_v2 -f && 
git push <remotename> branch/app_v2 -f

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK here is the cookbook :

**on the Git repo** , create the remote branch ( note it is the same revision as SVN's c75e75c but it doesn't have the same has name on the other git repo )

```
git checkout -b <branch_name> <revision_hash>
```

then push the branch to remote repo

```
git push origin <branch_name>
```

**on SVN repo** , roll back to the revision to push

```
git checkout c75e75c
```

push to the remote branch

```
git push origin <current_locale_branch>:<branch_name>
```

Any questions ?