# Unsuccessful git push – cannot push again

Tags: git

I want to push commits into two repositories like this:

```
[remote "origin"]
    url = https://mrtnzlml@bitbucket.org/mrtnzlml/www.zeminem.cz.git
    url = https://github.com/mrtnzlml/www.zeminem.cz.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

Works (almost) perfectly until today. Last push (via PhpStorm IDE) caused this error:

```
Push failed
error: Connection time-out while accessing https://mrtnzlml@bitbucket.org/mrtnzlml/www.zeminem.cz.git/info/refs?service=git-receive-pack
fatal: HTTP request failed
```

Unfortunately there are not these commits on the remote servers and I cannot see them on localhost anymore (using `git status`). But I found `get reflog` commmand:

```
91a20c9 HEAD@{0}: checkout: moving from pictures to develop
7829ccc HEAD@{1}: commit: WP like pictures draft
e59196f HEAD@{2}: checkout: moving from develop to pictures
```

How can I jump back to the `7829ccc` commit (without data lost) and try to repush it? I found some ridiculous solutions eg. make new git clone and copy changes from old project but I don't want to do that...

Comment: Try pushing to an SSH url instead of an HTTP one.

Comment: What is it changing @gravetii? Cannot push it again, because the commit seems pushed already. There are only changes I've made after this unsuccessful push...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yaay! (-: I finally solved this issue thank to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3230074/git-pushing-specific-commit).

So the solution is actually simple:

```
git push origin 7829ccc:pictures
```