# git push non for all the commits

Tags: git, push, commit

I have a problem about using `git push` on my project. I've 7 commits to push, but they are so big for my internet connection that I can't complete the command.

So I'd like to push the oldest commit, than the second, and so on.

What are the commands to see the commit's name and to push them one at time?

Comment: possible duplicate of [git - pushing specific commit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3230074/git-pushing-specific-commit)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say you have an historic like this:

```
A -- B -- C -- D -- E -- F -- G -- H
|                                  |
origin/master                      master
```

What you want to do is to push only commit `B` first, then only `C`, and so on, and so forth.

To do this, you can use several times the command

```
git push <remote name> <local commit to push>:<remote branch>
```

ie: use the the successive commands

```
git push origin B:master
git push origin C:master
...
git push origin H:master
```

where `B` should be replaced by the sha1 of the commit `B` (or by any other way to point at this commit. For example `master~6`)