# How to push a branch between a certain versions to another repo?

Tags: git

I know I can graft one branch of one git project (says 'old') to another one (says 'new') by running this command:

```
 cd old # location of the 'old' repo
 git push git:git@github.com:dude/new.git a-branch
```

However I do not want to push all the history of the branch to the new git project. I only want to include a subset of the commits in this branch.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply can specify the SHA1 you want to limit that branch to:

```
git push git:git@github.com:dude/new.git <SHA1>:abranch
```

All commits up to that `<SHA1>` will be pushed to a remote branch '`abranch`' on `new.git` repo.
See for example:

- "[Git push up to a certain commit](https://coderwall.com/p/hexinq/git-push-up-to-a-certain-commit) "
- "[git - pushing specific commit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3230241/6309)" (which also suggests [`git cherry-pick`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick) if you want only a range within the branch, instead of 'all commits up to and including `<SHA1>`)

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to push a subset of the history you must create a branch that contains only the subset of commits you want to push. So create a new branch based on your current

```
git checkout -b subsetOfCommits
```

than rebase in interactive mode.

```
git rebase -i firstCommitYouWantToChange
```

Use the rebase interactive editor and `squash`, `fixup`, move or delete the commits.

Finally push that branch to wherever you want.