# Git - How to reset a branch to the state before pushing to a commit

Tags: git, github, version-control, repository

Let's say I have on my remote origin 3 branches: master (HEAD), branch_A, branch B.

I did the followed push for branch_A and branch_B

```
git push origin <last commit SHA of master>:branch_A
git push origin <last commit SHA of master>:branch_B
```

Now all of my three branches are in the same state with all the changes of all commits up to the last commit in **master**, what I don't want to have. I did just want to have only the change in last commit of **master**. I should use followed command before the above commands as in [How can I pushing specific commit to a remote, and not the previous commits?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3230074/git-pushing-specific-commit#)

```
git rebase -i
```

But I did not do it. How can I reset the branch_A and branch_B to the state before the push commands?

Comment: Do you still have the local branches `branch_A` and `branch_B`? Are they still in the state before you pushed?

Comment: The problem is also i did not check out `branch_A` and `branch_B` so i don't have them on my local