# Push only some commits to another git repository

Tags: git, push

I have two remote `origin` and `another` repositories and, for example, commits history on `origin:master` repo:

```
A - B - C - D - E - F
```

`another` is empty repo.

Need to push only last two commits `E - F` to `another:master` i.e.:

```
origin:master: A - B - C - D - E - F
another:master: E - F
```

How I can do that with possibility after to push in this two remotes without rebase or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need a git history with an initial [empty commit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/645450/insert-a-commit-before-the-root-commit-in-git) and two branches: one (your current `master`) pointing to `F` and another one pointing to the empty commit.

Check out the branch pointing to the empty commit, `cherry-pick` `E` and `F`, and push this branch to your `another` remote. As you make changes that you want in the `another` repository, you'll simply `cherry-pick` them over.

So, after having created the initial commit:

```
git checkout -b another-branch <<SHA of empty initial commit>>
git cherry-pick <<SHA of E>>
git cherry-pick <<SHA of F>>
git push another another-branch
```

Comment: This solution oblidge me to have two branches and do `cherry-pick` on every commit in `master` after `F`, is there exists simpler solution?

Comment: No, because git keeps track of the **history** of a project. In your example, `E` depends on everything that has come before it, even if it's a commit that contains a new file that has not been touched by a previous commit. See [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3230074/git-pushing-specific-commit)