# Git - Cloning repository as read-only, committing only changes into another repository

Tags: git

I'm looking for an approach how to work with huge code-base from a read-only repository, without cloning/forking it into my remote repository.
Here is an imaginary scenario:

1. I've cloned locally a tag/branch from git-repository (let's name it *Original*), which I want to treat as *read-only*.
2. I've applied some changes locally.
3. Now I want to commit **only the changed files** (a kind of patches) into separate git-repository (let's name it *Patched*, I will create a new remote repo for that).
4. Repeat from the step 2.

Is this approach supported somehow by git?
And how can another developer get the *Original* repository with automagically applying changes from the *Patched* repositry?
I know I can clone the original repository and push it completely into my own, but even without history it is too huge, and I don't have enough resources for that on my server.
I was thinking about submodules, but still not sure how to set it up (overlaying submodules?), since I intend to modify a submodule.
I guess, needed setup may be possible with mixing VCSs like cloning a git-repo, and committing changes into a svn-repo.
Any other ideas?
Related topics:

- [Push only some commits to another git repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33476793/push-only-some-commits-to-another-git-repository)

Answer (score 0):

> Is this approach supported somehow by git?

In part yes, in the sense that you never commit to the original repository *anyway* – you can only commit to your clone, and only an explicit sync command (push or fetch) gets those commits back into the original (or some other remote).

What you cannot do is push *just* the changed files into your own remote. It's possible to have a truncated history (i.e. push to a "shallow clone" remote), and it's possible to have a partial history when cloning (filter objects), but as far as I know it's not possible to *push to* a filtered remote repository; you'll always push at least a whole commit with all the "current versions" of every file.

That being said, because commits in Git are always local, it sounds like you could work entirely within your local machine (maybe using branches, or having git-worktrees, or even two separate clones that share disk space via hardlinks).

> And how can another developer get the Original repository with automagically applying changes from the Patched repositry?

They would have to a) clone it from Patched; or b) clone from Original, then pull new commits from Patched; or c) clone from Original, then pull new commits from a bundle file that you create with `git bundle`. I *think* you might be able to host bundles as they're smaller (only including the changed objects or deltas).