# Git: how to re-push changes already pushed, but lost due to re-creation of staging version

Tags: wordpress, git, git-revert

We use WPEngine to host WordPress sites and push changes via Git to a staging version of the site - these can then be deployed to the production version via an internal script.

We staged the live site a few days ago and pushed up a number of changes via Git to the staged version.

Accidentally, one user pushed the button to recreate the staged version of the site and all our changes were lost - Git thinks that the local and remote are up-to-date - but of course, the staged version now shows the files in the form they are on the current live site.

Is there a way that we can force push up commits from the last x days or between two set hashes - or some other correct way to notify Git that the changes are no longer in sync?

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [git - pushing specific commit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3230074/git-pushing-specific-commit/3230241#3230241)

Answer (score 2):

`git push <remotename> <commit SHA>:<remotebranchname>` should do the trick, provided `<remotebranchname>` already exists on the remote.  If it doesn't, use `git push <remotename> <commit SHA>:refs/heads/<remotebranchname>`

Note that this pushes all commits up to and including the commit you choose.  If you don't want that to happen, you should first use `git rebase -i` to re-order the commits.

Note: Picked this from thread on SO : [git - pushing specific commit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3230074/git-pushing-specific-commit/3230241#3230241). Check it out for more details.

Comment: Thanks - I had read that thread but running the command gives me "everything up-to-date" - so this does not resolve the problem

Comment: Running previous sha values other than the most recent tells me "tip of the current branch is behind.."

Comment: @QStudio That's strange. As I have followed this approach to push old commits again and it worked fine for me. Let me check.

Comment: @QStudio Actually just wondering, can't you just perform a merge of the older branch on new master/staging branch so as to apply all the commits in the  branch?

Comment: When I pull from the staging it gives "already up to date"... It does not find anything to merge - how can I force this?

Answer (score 1):

I have had a similar issue when I have had to restore a site from a backup on WP Engine. What works for me is to just change something in a file.

1. Add a return at the end of any tracked file (any change at all will do)
2. Commit change
3. git push to remote

This should make sure everything matches local, adding/deleting/changing where needed, not just the last commit.

Comment: This worked for me as well, but it seems so clunky. I have so many "dumb change to kick prod loose" commits :'(

Comment: I agree. I feel like there should be a better way of doing it. Could be an issue with "bare" repositories since they don't keep branches? Not even sure that's what WP Engine is using.