# Can specific commits be pushed to a branch graphically, by GitKraken or any other alternative?

Tags: git, git-branch, git-commit, gitkraken

As said [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3230074/how-can-i-push-a-specific-commit-to-a-remote-and-not-previous-commits) and specifically answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4512933/826815), one can push specific commits (and everything before them) to a branch by writing on a terminal

```
git push <remotename> <commit SHA>:<remotebranchname>
// example -> git push origin 712acff81033eddc90bb2b45e1e4cd031fefc50f:master
```

The question is, can this be done **graphically** in **GitKraken**? If not, is there **any program** that can do this through a graphical interface?

**The reasoning of wanting to push specific commits is to sort-of deploy on a controlled manner different updates of a website, which is synced to a github repository (netlify)*

Comment: I don't think GitKraken can currently do this... Hell, you can't even _check out_ a specific commit yet. :)

Comment: Yes, I've come to the same conclusion :)