# Git pack exceeds limit

Tags: git, git-bash

Hello I have been receiving the following error when I am trying to push a commit to my branch in my Git Desktop. The error is as follows:

```
Enumerating objects: 14181, done.
Counting objects: 100% (14181/14181), done.
Delta compression using up to 64 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (8094/8094), done.
remote: fatal: pack exceeds maximum allowed size        s
error: RPC failed; curl 55 Send failure: Connection was aborted
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
Writing objects: 100% (14180/14180), 4.55 GiB | 14.97 MiB/s, done.
Total 14180 (delta 8863), reused 11393 (delta 6076), pack-reused 0
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
Everything up-to-date
```

I have tried few solutions from online, such as increasing the buffer size from git bash:

```
git config http.postBuffer 524288000
```

and

```
git gc --aggressive
```

but none of them worked to resolve this issue. What could be the problem?

Comment: @rbento I have only read about push origin which does push in one go. But how do I split the push?

Comment: Splitting commits: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6217156/break-a-previous-commit-into-multiple-commits

Comment: Pushing individual commits: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3230074/how-can-i-push-a-specific-commit-to-a-remote-and-not-previous-commits

Comment: You should also consider using `git lfs` for the large files in that commit. The presence of large files in your repo will likely cause you trouble in the future, which can easily be avoided with `lfs`.

Comment: @joanis I have already used git lfs. There is .gitattributes available in the repo too.