# How can I push specific files to GitLab after I have committed multiple files (including those which I need to push) in a local repository?

Tags: git, gitlab, push

I have already committed the following files in the local Git repository:

- dir1/file1
- dir1/file2
- dir2/file3
- dir2/file4

Now I want to push only two files out of four files, i.e., *dir1/file1* and *dir2/fil4* to GitLab. Is it possible? If yes, what is the appropriate Git command?

Comment: The simple answer is "no": you don't push _files_, you push _commits_. The longer answer is that there are many ways of making a _new_ commit, but they require more details about what you're trying to achieve, and are probably well documented if you read some general git tutorials.

Answer (score 2):

I think this might be a duplicate of [How can I push a specific commit to a remote, and not previous commits?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3230074/how-can-i-push-a-specific-commit-to-a-remote-and-not-previous-commits)?

I'll warn you that the `rebase` command that answer mentions can be a bit confusing.

Depending on why you don't want to push all of the files:

- If you only meant to commit 2 of the 4 in the first place you can use `git reset --soft <the-commit-hash-before-you-commited>`. Then you can re-add only the files you want to commit. BUT if you have already pushed some of those commits to remote then you have to do a `--force` push, which you may not have permission to do.
- If you never wanted those files to be committed at all, you should add them to the `.gitignore` so they don't come up again.