# How to push only new changes from branch B without commits from an un-merged branch A even though branch B is created from branch A

Tags: git

I have an unmerged branch, A, which has some changes/commits. Then I checkout to a new branch based on A by `git checkout -b 'B'` from A.

I then make some new changes on B. I only want to push these new changes from B to the remote repository. How do I do that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I push a specific commit to a remote, and not previous commits?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3230074/how-can-i-push-a-specific-commit-to-a-remote-and-not-previous-commits)

Comment: Does the [More Interesting Rebases](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Rebasing#_more_interesting_rebases) section of the Pro Git book match your scenario (with the difference, that you want the result (also) on a remote repository)?

Answer (score 0):

On branch B you should do a `git log` to see the hashes of the commits you want to include. Then create a new branch C from the base branch (from which you created branch A). In this C branch you can then do `git cherry-pick abc123` a few times where abc123 is the commit hash you want to include. Make sure to add them from the oldest to the newest.

Answer (score 0):

Your current `B` branch has evolved from `A`.
If you push it now, it will contain `A` work.

But you can adapt `B` so that it has evolved from `main`, and then push it.
For this, you need to `rebase`.

- First `git checkout B` if not already on it
- Then rebase on main: `git rebase -i main`. This will open your editor with all the commits from `main` to `B`, including the ones from `A`.
- In this editor, remove the lines of the commits from `A`. Your new `B` branch won't have them.
- Close the editor, and see how things are going.

If the rebase is finished, you now have `B` based on `main` without any of the `A commits`. You can now `git push B -f`. The `-f` flag forces the push because `B` has changed its commits (this is discouraged on shared branchs, but OK if you're alone on it).

If the rebase has conflicts, you can abort all of this with `git rebase --abort`.
This means that your `B` work is dependent on the changes from `A` and cannot be used alone.

In this case, you either have to create a new branch `B2` from `main` and `cherry-pick` the `B` commits one by one in the same order of their creation.
Or the fast ugly way: simply copy/paste the work from `B` to `B2`, and continue from there.