# Specifying nth outstanding git commit, relative to upstream branch

Tags: git

As I was reading [git: push a single commit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1789017/git-push-a-single-commit) and thinking about pushing commits in small batches, I started wondering if I could specify the local revision relative to the number of commits I want to push at once.

For example, let's say I have 12 outstanding commits to push. I can use `HEAD~9` to push the first 3 outstanding commits; to push the next 3, I have to use `HEAD~6` and so on. But I'd like to be able to use my shell's history without having to edit it for each batch.

```
$ git log --oneline myremote/mybranch..mybranch
0a594a4 Blah blah 12
9a4b42e Blah blah 11
d81227e Blah blah 10
803f1d3 Blah blah 9
aa7dcbc Blah blah 8
fc410e6 Blah blah 7
d57198e Blah blah 6
75f8ed6 Blah blah 5
4e801b4 Blah blah 4
7333461 Blah blah 3
3bc453e Blah blah 2
562690f Blah blah 1
```

Obviously I can push 1-3 with `git push myremote 7333461:mybranch`, I can also use `HEAD~9:mybranch`, but is there any way to say something like `myremote/mybranch+3`, to get the same hash? Everything I've tried with `rev-parse` takes me backwards, relative either to *HEAD* or *myremote/mybranch* (when it works at all).

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I find the next commit in git?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2263674/how-do-i-find-the-next-commit-in-git)

Comment: Hm... Possibly by specifying the src ref with command substitution in the shell but yuck -- I was hoping for something cleaner. (I'm not sure I'd call it a duplicate, either, since getting from your question to the answer I want is non-obvious and non-trivial.)

Comment: You're right, it only gets you about 80% there. You'd have to build your own alias. I retracted the vote to close.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bad news is there cannot be an equivalent to HEAD^ that looks forward because the Git commit structure only knows about its parents.  Sorry.  You can write a utility to do it.

It has to have somewhere to look into the past from.  You *could* accomplish this by walking back from each branch or tag until you find HEAD, but that could require a full tree traversal (not as inefficient as you'd think) and ambiguous.

However, your specific question has a crib.  You can look backwards from the current branch's remote branch, [which is available as `@{u}`](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitrevisions) ("u" for "upstream").  Put this program into your PATH as `git-unpushed-ref` or something.

```
#!/bin/sh

NUMBER=$1

git log --pretty=format:%H @{u}..HEAD | tail -n$NUMBER | head -n1
```

Now you can write `git push origin $(git unpushed-ref 3):master` or build a little shell wrapper around that.

Comment: I think I misunderstood the intentions of your other question.  If you are only interested in the branch you are currently on just nuke your tracking_branch function and replace `$remote_branch` with `@{u}`

Comment: @AndrewC Brilliant!  Of course Git uses *yet another term* for the same thing so I can't find it in the docs.