# Why does cherry-pick not take all changes?

Tags: git, cherry-pick

I have the following situation in my commit history:

```
A1-...-A2
         \
          B1-B2-...-B3----------B4-B5
                      \        /
                       C1-C2-C3
```

I then did (after `git checkout A2` and a clean `git status`) 
`git cherry-pick --no-commit C2..B5`.
Now, `C2` introduced an important line in `file1.txt`, say

```
file1.txt
-line x
+line x with new part
```

and "line x with new part" exists in all commits C2 to B5.
But after the cherry-pick, the change does not appear and `file1.txt` still looks like

```
...
line x
...
```

where I expected a line "line x with new part". 
I thought, I don't understand the changes and did

```
git diff HEAD C2 file1.txt
file1.txt
-line x
+line x with new part
```

which shows the change as expected. I also checked
`git diff HEAD C3 file1.txt`, `git diff HEAD B4 file1.txt`
 and `git diff HEAD B5 file1.txt` with the same result.

`git rev-parse HEAD` results in `A2` as intended and `git status`
says "On branch A, Your branch is up to date with 'origin/A'. 
nothing to commit, working tree clean".

What do I miss? Any ideas?

References:
[How to cherry pick a range of commits and merge into another branch](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1994463/5784831),
[How to merge a specific commit in Git](https://stackoverflow.com/q/881092/5784831) and
[Pull all commits from a branch, push specified commits to another](https://stackoverflow.com/q/880957/5784831) (I hope, 
it is not an issue with a comment from the answer "...Likewise, cherry picking a commit from one branch to another basically involves generating a patch, 
then applying it, thus losing history that way as well." from the answer.).

**Edit @eftshift0:** After `git cherry-pick --no-commit C1..B5` it looks correct at a first glance:
The Diff shows

```
<<<<<<< HEAD
line x                         # current status of A2
||||||| parent of C2...
line x                         # common ancestors of C1 and A2
=======
line x with new part           # from merge (new stuff)
>>>>>>> C2...
```

From the docs:

> git-cherry-pick - Apply the changes introduced by some existing
>   commits SYNOPSIS
>
> DESCRIPTION
>   Given one or more existing commits, apply the change each one
>   introduces, recording a new commit for each. This requires your
>   working tree to be clean (no modifications from the HEAD commit).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you are saying `C2..B5`, the change from `C2` is not considered. try `C1..B2`.

Comment: Could you explain, why you need one more commit? If you look at any combination A2-X (X=C2, ...) the change is displayed in the diff. Does cherry-pick relay on something else? I made a dummy example and it worked as expected (I thought).

Comment: See my edit... It seems, you are right, but I am quite confused. As the code is used "in production" I would like to understand, why you are right. Thanks!

Comment: Explanation is pretty straight forward. When you use cherry-pick with a range of revisions, the _first_ revision that is just the starting point and it is not applied on. The revisions following it are the ones that will be applied on top of where you are working... so if you wanted to see the change that is coming from C2 to be applied on where you are working, you have to specify C1 as the starting point... and what do you mean I _seem_ to be right? I **am** right. :-D

Comment: Ok :-) I read the documentation and I still would not get your point from the docs. Are the docs clear to you with respect to this question?

Comment: you mean, do I find an inconsistency there? I might take a look and send over a patch if I think wording might be improved.

Comment: Yes: to me, the doc is not clear, but perhaps this is because I am not a native speaker...

Comment: See e.g. here https://stackoverflow.com/a/30218784/5784831: ...The command git cherry-pick commit applies the changes introduced by the named commit on the current branch.

Comment: @Christoph: Git consistently uses ranges this way. It's annoying for the cherry-pick case in particular when you're using it the way you are, but if cherry-pick acted differently, that would be tricky to explain and model, because ranges don't mean what they look like in the first place. That is, `X..Y` does not mean "start at X and work forward to Y". It actually means "start at Y and work backwards all the way through time. Then, start at X and work backwards all the way through time. Take the *second* group of commits away from the *first* one."

Comment: Git actually *has* to do this internally, because its internal working *are* all backwards. But then, rather than make user friendly interfaces, Git just exposes these inner workings directly to you. :-)

Comment: @torek One change which was introduced in C3 (and not reverted or changed afterwards) is also missing after `git cherry-pick --no-commit C1..B5`. Does that make sense to you? `B4` was a `-no-ff` commit. By the way: When I see, what git expects the user to know, I consider my question as valuable ;-)

Comment: The range expression `C1..B5` should include C3, and cherry-picking C3 will use C2 as a merge base and C3 as the other commit. The result will follow the usual merge rules. Note, however, that since B4 is a merge commit, it cannot be cherry-picked as part of a range operation: cherry-picking B4 requires specifying *which parent* to use as it has two, while the others require *not specifying which parent to use* as they have only one.