# how to merge all files from one branch to another branch but except one file

Tags: git

Suppose,

One Branch:

```
file1,
No-add-another-branch
file3
```

Another Branch:

```
file1, 
file2, 
....
```

I want to merge all files from One Branch into another branch except "No-add-another-branch" file.

I can do move "No-add-another-branch" file to somewhere place and merge One Branch into another branch but I am looking for a shortcut way. or
git way.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to prevent git merge to merge a specific file from trunk into a branch and vice versa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/773220/how-to-prevent-git-merge-to-merge-a-specific-file-from-trunk-into-a-branch-and-v)

Answer (score 0):

1. merge One Branch into Another Branch normally (including `No-add-another-branch`)
2. stage deletion of `No-add-another-branch` (using `git rm No-add-another-beanch`)
3. amend the merge commit (`git commit --amend`)

An alternative is to delete the file in a temporary branch before merging. This creates one extra commit but makes the merge cleaner and the history will be more obvious to read.

1. `git checkout -b tmp OneBranch`
2. `git rm No-add-another-branch` followed by `git commit -m 'Remove the file before merging`
3. `git checkout AnotherBranch` and `git merge tmp`
4. `git branch -d tmp`

The history should then look like this:

```
 o--o--o--o Another Branch
         /
        o Remove the file before merging
       /
o--o--o One Branch
```

---

If, instead of removing the file, you want to keep it unchanged, you can either replace step 2 of the first approach by `git checkout AnotherBranch^ -- No-add-another-branch` (i.e., restore its previous version before the merge), or replace step 2 of the second approach by `git checkout AnotherBranch -- No-add-another-branch` followed by `git commit -m 'Make the file equal to Another Branch before merging'`.

Comment: I thought we can only adds file before "git commit -amend"

Comment: You can also delete, rename, or change files, or change the commit message.

Comment: I just came out with additional question: What if both branches have one same file name but don't want to merge them. I mean merge everything except that same files name from both branches