# Php multiple db environment with git & phpfog

Tags: php, mysql, git, phpfog

I have a plain(no framework) php app. I want to deploy my app to PhpFog.
The problem is the config(host,dbname) is different.

**How to create a db config for development and production environment?**

Comment: Change those settings in your source file.

Comment: I did, I managed to deploy. But i lost my development config. Should i gitignore the config file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use environment variables to do this. PHPFog provides a way to set environment variables in the **App Console > Env. Variables** tab for your app.

Simply create all the environment variables that you need on both your local machine and on the App Console:

**Example:**

Local Machine: Edit your [.bash_profile](http://www.mcsr.olemiss.edu/unixhelp/environment/env3db.html)

```
APP_HOST=localhost
APP_DATABASE=mydatabase
```

PHPfog App Console:

```
APP_HOST=production.mysqlserver.com
APP_DATABASE=proddatabase
```

Then access them from your php app:

```
$db_host = getenv("APP_HOST");
$db_name = getenv("APP_DATABASE");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can put your `config.php` in your [`.gitignore`](http://gitmanual.org/gitignore.html) or another solution is to have two [branches](http://gitmanual.org/git-branch.html) on your local repository. One to work locally and one to push. Then you define a special [merge strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8014154):

> Let's say you want to exclude the file config.php
>
> On branch A:
>
> Create a file named '.gitattributes' in the same dir, with this line:
>   config.php merge=ours. This tells git what strategy to use when mergin
>   the file. In this case it always keep your version, ie. the version on
>   the branch you are merging into.
>
> Add the .gitattributes file and commit
>
> On branch B: repeat steps 1-2
>
> Try merging now. Your file should be left untouched.