# Git - Same file with different versions on two branches, when merge do not want to overwrite

Tags: git, branching-and-merging, multiple-versions

We have two branches -- 'master' and 'release'

And we have one file, like `fileA`, we want to keep different version on these two branches.

But each time, we have to merge 'release' into 'master', how can we achieve, the `fileA` in 'master' will not be overwritten by the `fileA` in branch 'release'.

Comment: might have already been answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3868491/git-ignore-some-files-during-a-merge-keep-some-files-restricted-to-one-branch)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

[Pro Git](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2) describes how to get this effect in the [“Merge Strategies”](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Attributes#_merge_strategies) section of [8.2 Customizing Git — Git Attributes](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Attributes).

> #### Merge Strategies
>
> You can also use Git attributes to tell Git to use
>   different merge strategies for specific files in your project. One
>   very useful option is to tell Git to not try to merge specific files
>   when they have conflicts, but rather to use your side of the merge
>   over someone else’s.
>
> This is helpful if a branch in your project has diverged or is
>   specialized, but you want to be able to merge changes back in from it,
>   and you want to ignore certain files. Say you have a database settings
>   file called `database.xml` that is different in two branches, and you
>   want to merge in your other branch without messing up the database
>   file. You can set up an attribute like this:
>
> ```
> database.xml merge=ours
> ```
>
> And then define a dummy `ours` merge strategy with:
>
> ```
> $ git config --global merge.ours.driver true
> ```
>
> If you merge in the other branch, instead of having merge conflicts
>   with the `database.xml` file, you see something like this:
>
> ```
> $ git merge topic
> Auto-merging database.xml
> Merge made by recursive.
> ```
>
> In this case, `database.xml` stays at whatever version you originally
>   had.

Applying it to your situation, first create `fileA`

```
$ echo 'master fileA' > fileA
$ git add fileA ; git commit -m "master fileA"
[master (root-commit) fba9f1a] master fileA
 1 files changed, 1 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
 create mode 100644 fileA
```

and make it special.

```
$ echo fileA merge=ours > .gitattributes
$ git add .gitattributes ; git commit -m 'fileA merge=ours'
[master 98e056f] fileA merge=ours
 1 files changed, 1 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
 create mode 100644 .gitattributes
$ git config --global merge.ours.driver true
```

Now we create a representative `release` branch.

```
$ git checkout -b release
Switched to a new branch 'release'
$ echo 'release fileA' > fileA
$ git add fileA ; git commit -m 'release fileA'
[release 53f3564] release fileA
 1 files changed, 1 insertions(+), 1 deletions(-)
```

Nothing special has happened yet: version control is merely working as it’s supposed to at this point.

Now, we implement *Feature B* back on `master`.

```
$ git checkout master
Switched to branch 'master'
$ touch featureB ; echo 'With Feature B' >> fileA
$ git add featureB fileA ; git commit -m 'Feature B'
[master 443030f] Feature B
 1 files changed, 1 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
 create mode 100644 featureB
```

Try to contain your excitement.

Here is where our special merge driver comes into play. Our hero wants to merge the new code from `master` into `release`. First switch branches.

```
$ git checkout release
Switched to branch 'release'
```

Sanity check that `fileA` contains what we expect.

```
$ cat fileA
release fileA
```

Merge *Feature B* from `master`.

```
$ git merge master
Auto-merging fileA
Merge made by recursive.
 0 files changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
 create mode 100644 featureB
```

The line `Auto-merging fileA` is a clue that something special happened. Indeed:

```
$ cat fileA
release fileA
```

---

## How It Works

The section [“Defining a custom merge driver”](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes#_defining_a_custom_merge_driver) in the [gitattributes documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes) explains.

> The `merge.*.driver` variable’s value is used to construct a command to
>   run to merge ancestor’s version (`%O`), current version (`%A`) and the
>   other branches' version (`%B`). These three tokens are replaced with the
>   names of temporary files that hold the contents of these versions when
>   the command line is built …
>
> The merge driver is expected to leave the result of the merge in the
>   file named with `%A` by overwriting it, and exit with zero status if it
>   managed to merge them cleanly, or non-zero if there were conflicts.

The custom `ours` driver uses almost none of this machinery, only the [`true` command](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/True_and_false_(commands)) to exit with zero status. This achieves the desired effect because it starts with `fileA` from whichever branch we’re currently on — which is the result we want — then does nothing in the merge-overwrite phase (*i.e.*, ignores the other branch’s version named by `%B`), and finally tells git all is well with a successful exit status.

Comment: Thanks for the wonderful explanation, this is what I was looking for, you saved my day @GregBacon

Comment: @ChiragKhatri You’re welcome! I’m glad my answer helped.

Comment: .gitattributes to set merge strategies is still not supported by some git hosts (e.g. Azure DevOps Repos), so when you go to open a PR you still get a merge conflict bc the server doesn't use .gitattributes to do the merge :/