# How to restrict specific files when merging two local Git branches using Xcode

Tags: xcode, git, merge

This is my scenario. I'm having two Git branches and we will name them as "Aaa" and "Bbb". Remotely there are two separate Git locations for those two as well. So I can commit and push remotely with unique changes to there branches.

What I curious is, when I need to merge those two branches, I don't want some specific files to be merged at all. As an example in my Xcode project, I don't want info.plist file to be merged when I'm trying to merge above mentioned two branches but need to merge AppDelegate.m

Is there any way that I can write a script or add some lines in .gitignore file to achieve that task.

If I explain it further more, it is like, when I add some files to .gitignore, local changes to that files is not affecting to remote git server files. I want to know such kind of behaviour is existing with merging two local branches.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/a/8014154

Comment: I waited to comment this, because I had some doubt that is not the exact answer that I'm looking for. Just like I thought, the provided link is giving me _The file .gitattributes had a tree conflict._ message when I'm trying to merge from branch "Bbb".