# How do I combine versioning with merge-only to master git workflow?

Tags: git, versioning, git-flow

In a reasonable "merge-only to master" git workflow (e.g. gitflow) - all changes happen in branches, which in turn get merged (perhaps as part of a Pull Request) - how do I handle versioning?

For tagging, I easily can `git tag` the particular merge commit, no big deal.

But many app frameworks rely on a version file (e.g. `package.json` or `gemspec` or even custom files).

I see a few options:

1. Modify the file as part of the branch. This isn't great, since you rarely know in advance which version will get merged in first, especially with a large team with many branches running in parallel.
2. Modify the file *after* commit. This isn't great, since a- I now commit to master, and b- automated CI/CD will grab the previous commit and release it, but it has the old version number and c- with 2 commits to master for one release, it is possible to check out the wrong version; easy human error.
3. Make the version file a template and auto-generate it from the git tag. This, too, isn't great, since local tooling will break on it (try running `npm <anything>` with an invalid `package.json`), and the repo no longer can stand on its own as an atomic unit.

Is there a reasonably standard way to do this when versioning is in a file that is part of the commit?

Answer (score 1):

You might employ a strategy that humans may contribute to master branch via merge-only, and only automated CI/CD (e.g. Jenkins) may change content of version file directly in master. The automated **release** process from CI/CD standpoint might look like this:

1. pull master (master **code freeze** starts)
2. run pre-release build (with old version)
3. increment content of ver file and commit
4. run release build with new release version (differs from #2 by content of ver file)
5. push master to central repo (possibly with `--force`, if someone violated master **code freeze**)

As an addition, you may protect ver file from merge-to-master changes with `.gitattributes` in ver file directory with content `verfile merge=ours` (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3868491/git-ignore-some-files-during-a-merge-keep-some-files-restricted-to-one-branch))

Comment: Most of that I have, thanks @IrLED. The key to your suggestion is to have the versioning file changed only by CI/CD? The challenge to that is that there often is a lot more in there than just version. Think `package.json` or `Gemfile`. Much of it legitimately needs to change during normal dev process; just one field needs control.

Comment: >The key to your suggestion is to have the versioning file changed only by CI/CD?
Yes, that's the point. To separate protected part from publicly available, you can run sort of pre-processing of `package.json` - inject a value from ver file.

Comment: I need to think that through a bit. It would require some pretty brittle logic - per-file-type as well - to enable users to change everything but that one line.

Comment: in case of JSON - during pre-processing you deserialize the `package.json` in ruby (i assume you use it, by mentioning `Gemfile`), unconditionally overwrite/add `"version" : "1.0.0"` in that structure and serialize it back => users are free to change `package.json` how they want, but during the release the field "version" will have the value from protected ver.file

Comment: It is an interesting approach. I am surprised I have not seen some sort of large-scale solution to this given the popularity of master-merge-only git flows.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like what want is a template version file in the repository that then gets built into the actual version file as part of the normal build system with info extracted from the repository.

I would suggest [Autorevision](https://autorevision.github.io/) to get the version info from the repository into form that is easy use to do this.

Comment: Similar to @IrLED's approach, with specific tool, thanks. I think I will try some combination of the two.