# How to have different yml file for different branch in Serverless framework

Tags: git, aws-lambda, serverless-framework

I use Serverless framework for managing my AWS lambda function. And I also use git for managing with other developer. I have 2 branch which is development and production. If the feature is ready for release, we will merge the development branch into the master which is my production branch.

My question is, is there any way to seperate the `provider` and `functions` configuration in .yml file ? I need to ignore the `provider` section, so each branch has its own config, but I need the `functions` to be updated from development stage to production stage.

Comment: Take look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8014154/5563916).

Comment: Thank you for answering. I know how to implement the git ignore, but how to create the yml file seperately ? I want the provider section to be different in each branch, which is I don't track it. And I want the functions section to always be updated which is I need to track these files

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using some kind of env variable to determine the state `dev` and `prod`.

you could have something like this:

`serverless.yml`

```
...
provider: ${file(./path_to_extra_yaml/${env:STATE}-provider.yml)}
...
```

then you can have extra confirgurations for the provider

`dev-provider.yml`

```
...
name: aws
region: us-west-1
runtime: java
...
```

`prod-provider.yml`

```
...
name: aws
region: us-west-2
runtime: java
...
```

Comment: Thanks !! This is what I'm looking for