How to prevent GitLab CI configuration changes from being merged into the prod branch when merging?
I have a GitLab CI/CD pipeline setup for two branches: dev and prod. Each branch has its own pipeline configuration tailored to its environment. For example:
dev branch pipeline runs with only: dev.
prod branch pipeline runs with only: Prod.
The problem arises when the dev team pushes changes to the dev branch and modifies the .gitlab-ci.yml for development purposes.
When the dev branch changes are cherry-picked into the prod branch, the .gitlab-ci.yml configuration of prod is not affected because cherry-picking specific commits excludes unrelated changes.
However, if a merge request is created from dev to prod, all commits are merged, including changes to .gitlab-ci.yml. This leads to the prod branch inadvertently inheriting the dev pipeline configuration, which can cause deployment issues in the production environment.
My Question:
Is this behavior expected when performing a merge request?
How can I avoid .gitlab-ci.yml changes for the dev environment from being merged into the prod branch?
I want to know if my understanding of the situation is correct and How can I avoid .gitlab-ci.yml changes for the dev environment from being merged into the prod branch?

Does this help https://stackoverflow.com/a/8014154/1862861?

I am not sure I understand one part correctly: If you have 2 different jobs, each targeting their own branch, why would it matter for Prod if anything is changed on Dev?

@Salketer let's say
dev has only: dev and deployment to this ip 10.0.1.12 (for example)
and prod triggered because has only: prod and deployment to another server
merging request from dev to prod (will have commit updating gitlab ci of dev) this will cause an issue Ithink the prod branch inadvertently inheriting the dev pipeline configuration is that right?
so how to avoid this (I know cherry pick will solve the issue will choose only commit that involve code changes not gitlab pipeline changes)
but is there other solution if the team do merge request

in my opinion, the best solution is to remove the pipeline into its own project and include it as a component, such that there are no dev vs prod differences..

I never had any problem with this... only: dev will only trigger on the dev branch. When merging dev to prod it will not be triggered. Again, I am only supposing that you are using it somewhat like we are, but without any gitlab-ci.yml example to express your need it is hard to do better.

Yes, your situation is understandable. To avoid problems with merging your dev pipeline configuration into your prod configuration, you can create separate pipeline configuration files, such as .gitlab-ci-dev.yml and .gitlab-ci-prod.yml. You can then run the correct pipeline based on the branch name. I will provide sample code for the .gitlab-ci.yml file.
stages: 
    - build
    - test
    - deploy

include:
    - local '.gitlab-ci-${CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME}.yml'


The CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME is a GitLab predefined variable that returns the branch name (dev or prod).
local: ".gitlab-ci-${CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME}.yml": This will dynamically reference the correct configuration file based on the branch name.

To get more understanding, you can refer it: CI/CD YAML syntax reference

so I will try this and give you update

@ZakariaAitYakoub Ok, sure. Please try and let me know if you have any other problems. I will help you.
