# git workflow: Can I prevent a certain file from being merged to another branch but still keep it under version control?

Tags: git, workflow, git-merge

I have a repository with two branches: live and stage. The repository holds code for a web based application. I would like to maintain two different .htaccess files for the stage and live branches, but still keep them version controlled, since the nature of serving a stage site is a little bit different (right now for instance, I want the caches to be timed differently).

I'm a novice with git so there is probably an easy explanation, but I'd like to have a workflow where when I was in live and I pulled changes (simple `git merge stage`), I didn't overwrite the existing .htaccess in the live branch. Is there any way to configure this? Am I missing some big concept in git?

Likewise, there is also a chunk of a (but possibly many) .html files where I would like to keep track of changes but not merge them back into live. Just to be clear I want live and stage to got keep track of changes in these files, but know not to merge those certain changes when doing merges.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

I found an [answer on another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3970442/88709) on Stack Overflow, credit goes to fcurella:

> Let's say you want to exclude the file `config.php`
>
> On branch A:
>
> 1. Create a file named `.gitattributes` in the same dir, with this line: `config.php merge=ours`. This tells git what strategy to use when merging the file. In this case it always keep your version, ie. the version on the branch you are merging into.
> 2. Add the `.gitattributes` file and commit
>
> On branch B: repeat steps 1-2
>
> Try merging now. Your file should be left untouched.

This seems like a more scalable solution.

Comment: It works only in case there is conflict in config.php while merging otherwise it doesn't work and overwrites the file.

Comment: yes but this is the most important : in my case , i want to sync a fork from parent repository without my css files to be modified.

Comment: @Charles-AntoineFournel if someone modifies something in _live_ but you haven't touched it in _stage_, your files in _stage_ will be overwritten, regardless of .gitattributes above

Comment: In case of `composer.lock`, I want it to be indicated as conflicting for manual regeneration after unsuccessful merge.

Answer (score 10):

Ankur, try this:

Assuming you're checked out on the live branch, run:

```
git merge --no-commit --no-ff stage
```

This will merge the two branches, but instead of making a new commit, will fail and leave these changes in your index file and working directory. Now since you want to keep your `.htaccess` file intact on the live branch, you can checkout this file from live:

```
git checkout live .htaccess
```

Now your working tree has all the changes from stage with the exception of `.htaccess`, and so you can finalize the merge commit:

```
git commit -m "Pulled changes from stage" -a
```

Comment: that's the general idea, but this doesn't scale well if i have 5-10 more files that eventually have differences. i would have to track those on my own.

Comment: If you have many more files that you'd like to preserve across these merges, then perhaps you can put these in their own empty branches (one for the live site, one for the stage site). That way, you can proceed as normal when doing merge commits between the live and stage branches, but still have separate branches for tracking changes to .htaccess and the rest of your static html files.

Answer (score 3):

To avoid overwriting problem encountered with [@ankur](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4520363/5784834)'s answer. Start by defining a merge driver that would always favor our current version of the file, by making use of the existing true command. We’ll call this driver ours, to keep in line with similar merge strategies:

`git config --global merge.ours.driver true`

After that we can implement the [@ankur](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4520363/5784834) solution:

> Let's say you want to exclude the file .env
>
> On branch A (e.g. Master):
>
> 1. Create a file named *.gitattributes* in the same dir, with this line:
>
>    ```
>    .env merge=ours
>    ```
>
>    This tells git what strategy to use when merging the file. In this case it always keep your version, ie. the version on the branch you are merging into.
> 2. Add the .gitattributes file and commit
>
> On branch B (e.g. Develop): repeat steps 1-2
>
> Try merging now. Your file should be left untouched.

Read [this](https://medium.com/@porteneuve/how-to-make-git-preserve-specific-files-while-merging-18c92343826b) for further explanations