# How Can I Easily Set Secrets on Git Checkout?

Tags: git, passwords, git-clone, git-checkout, secret-key

In popular products like GitLab, you can use a CI/CD pipeline to set passwords and other sensitive information during deployment.

Is it possible for me to also do this when a developer clones the repository or checks out a specific branch?

Let's suppose I have the following remote file in Master, Production, Test and Development branches of Git:

**config.txt**
BufferSize=4096
Password=%passwordGoesHere%
BackgroundColor=Blue

When a developer clones the repository, I want the config.txt file of all accessible branches to be updated with the appropriate password.

I think [VonC](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6309/vonc) mentions filter drivers at [A] and [B], but I'm unsure how to create a filter driver.  Also, from my limited understanding, a filter driver may not work on a per branch basis anyway per [torek](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1256452/torek) [C]

[A] - [Can git automatically switch between spaces and tabs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2316677/can-git-automatically-switch-between-spaces-and-tabs)
[B] - [web.config and app.config machine-specific settings in git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10142213/web-config-and-app-config-machine-specific-settings-in-git)
[C] - [git how to keep a config file different in different branches?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63628756/git-how-to-keep-a-config-file-different-in-different-branches)

*NOTE: I apologize if the SO community feels this question might be a duplicate*

Comment: Branches are now possible with content filter driver, since Git 2.27: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60905975/6309