# Can I keep a branch in sync with main except for specific files?

Tags: git

Is it possible to keep a feature branch totally in sync with the main branch except for a couple of specific files?

So for example I have a branch I create specifically for trying out a new style which has some changes to a css file, I'm not sure whether to go with the new style but I want to keep the option open while I continue to work on my app in main... when I switch back to my style branch all my progress in main is no longer there so I can't see what my updated app looks like with my alternate style..

So to keep the 2 in sync while excluding the style file would be perfect!

I've tried to look up how I might do this but haven't managed to come across what I'm looking for..

Thanks for any help you can give!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're already taking the right approach: create a separate branch for your "special CSS".

You can (and should) frequently merge changes in "main" back to your "dev" branch, to keep everything in sync.

Unless that particular CSS file is changing in "main", the merge shouldn't affect your branch.

Otherwise, you might consider looking into .gitattributes:

- [Can I prevent a certain file from being merged to another branch but still keep it under version control?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4520363/421195)
- [How to make Git preserve specific files while merging](https://medium.com/@porteneuve/how-to-make-git-preserve-specific-files-while-merging-18c92343826b)
- [gitattributes - Defining attributes per path](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes)

Comment: ah perfect thanks, the .gitattributes file seems to be doing the job! so to clarify, the best way to keep a feature branch is sync with main, is to simply go into the branch and then merge with main? so just kind of a habit to get into rather than something that can be automated?

Comment: Yes, exactly :)  And yes, if you wish, anything in Git can be "automated" (for example, write a script with the appropriate git command line(s)).

Answer (score 0):

You can merge your `main` branch to your `style` branch if your `css` files in `main` branch does not change.

If both `.css` files in your `main` branch and `style` are changed, you can create a new `dev` branch for developing new features, and only modify your styles in `main` branch or `style` branch. When preview with desired styles, just merge the `dev` branch to `main` branch or `style` branch, the styles will not affected as the style files are not modified in `dev` branch.