# Git : not ignored file in two branch needs to be different

Tags: git, configuration, configuration-files

I want to ask about what your approach looks like handling a situation like this: I have this setting file mongoid.yml, and I have two branches of the same project : master and dev. I haven't put mongoid.yml into gitignore because I need it to be in the commit when I push both branches. But whenever I edit it in either branch, for example, if I edited it in the dev branch, it shows up in git status, when I commit then merge dev to master, the master branch's mongoid is now looking like the one in dev. I need them to be different. How would you approach this? thanks!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use a different merge strategy on your file to prevent the merge.

Create a `.gitattributes` file with:

```
mongoid.yml merge=ours
```

Then when this file conflicts during a merge, the old one will be kept.

More infos [here](http://progit.org/book/ch7-2.html#merge_strategies) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332528/is-it-possible-to-exclude-specific-commits-when-doing-a-git-merge/3970442#3970442).

Comment: I think this does it, the link one's explanation basically is my question itself: avoid database config files being overwritten from another branch because they use different database tables. Thanks Michaël

Answer (score 0):

You want to make a dev branch and then check it out. Change the config file to what you need it to be. Switch back to the other branch.

```
git merge -s ours dev
```

This will ignore what you did in the dev branch, but still mark in the history as if those changes were already merged. From now on, when you merge to and from the dev branch, your config will stay as what you need it to be. This is the proper way to set up a development branch.

Hope this helps.

Comment: What happen if you change the file later (in dev or master)?

Comment: Thanks adymitruk I am going with Michaël Witrant's as the link in his example seems to be addressing my concern directly.

Answer (score -1):

You could keep your changes to the file in a separate commit always on top of master, and merge its parent.

For example:

- you work on `dev`,
- if you ever have to change `mongoid.yml`, you make commits with only this file changed,
- before you switch to `master`, you `git rebase -i master` and move your `mongoid.yml` commits to the bottom (and squash them all with the first one if there's more than one),
- then you switch to `master` and merge the parent of `dev`: `git merge dev^`

It's a little work on each merge and you loose the history of you changes on `mongoid.yml` in the dev branch, but it should work.